# How to use the Qt's PIMPL idiom?

Tags: c++, qt, pimpl-idiom

PIMPL stands for **P**ointer to **IMPL**ementation. The implementation stands for "implementation detail": something that the users of the class need not to be concerned with.

Qt's own class implementations cleanly separate out the interfaces from the implementations through the use of the PIMPL idiom. Yet, the mechanisms provided by Qt are undocumented. How to use them?

I'd like this to be the canonical question about "how do I PIMPL" in Qt. The answers are to be motivated by a simple coordinate entry dialog interface shown below.

The motivation for the use of PIMPL becomes apparent when we have anything with a semi-complex implementation. Further motivation is given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8972588/1329652). Even a fairly simple class has to pull in a lot of other headers in its interface.

[image: dialog screenshot]

The PIMPL-based interface is fairly clean and readable.

```
// CoordinateDialog.h
#include <QDialog>
#include <QVector3D>

class CoordinateDialogPrivate;
class CoordinateDialog : public QDialog
{
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE(CoordinateDialog)
#if QT_VERSION <= QT_VERSION_CHECK(5,0,0)
  Q_PRIVATE_SLOT(d_func(), void onAccepted())
#endif
  QScopedPointer<CoordinateDialogPrivate> const d_ptr;
public:
  CoordinateDialog(QWidget * parent = 0, Qt::WindowFlags flags = 0);
  ~CoordinateDialog();
  QVector3D coordinates() const;
  Q_SIGNAL void acceptedCoordinates(const QVector3D &);
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QVector3D)
```

A Qt 5, C++11 based interface doesn't need the `Q_PRIVATE_SLOT` line.

Compare that to a non-PIMPL interface that tucks implementation details into the private section of the interface. Note how much other code has to be included.

```
// CoordinateDialog.h
#include <QDialog>
#include <QVector3D>
#include <QFormLayout>
#include <QDoubleSpinBox>
#include <QDialogButtonBox>

class CoordinateDialog : public QDialog
{
  QFormLayout m_layout;
  QDoubleSpinBox m_x, m_y, m_z;
  QVector3D m_coordinates;
  QDialogButtonBox m_buttons;
  Q_SLOT void onAccepted();
public:
  CoordinateDialog(QWidget * parent = 0, Qt::WindowFlags flags = 0);
  QVector3D coordinates() const;
  Q_SIGNAL void acceptedCoordinates(const QVector3D &);
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QVector3D)
```

Those two interfaces are *exactly equivalent* as far as their public interface is concerned. They have the same signals, slots and public methods.

Comment: excellent faq. prevent having to read qt code.

Comment: There is some documentation here: https://wiki.qt.io/D-Pointer

Comment: This community post is nice, but I don't see the practical advantage of using the Qt way of implementing Pimpl since QxxxPrivate classes are not part of Qt's public API, and we cannot easily derive our impl classes from them. 
I don't really understand why they made a nice Qt wiki post about their use of d_ptr etc. if we're not really supposed to take advantage of it.
Maybe I'm missing something ?

Comment: What's considered "public API" is up to you. Obviously the Qt project maintains this code, it's in every class of theirs, pretty much, so not using it on the grounds of it not being "public" is something you do if you really want an excuse to reinvent the wheel. Otherwise - just use it. I have 100k+ lines of stuff that uses it. Who cares that it's not "public". Qt's source code is the public API as far as I'm concerned. It's out there for a reason: make it a module in your repo and use it and tweak it as you see fit!!

Comment: @foxesque Qt implements localized Bridge patterns as extension of Cheshire's cat pattern (that's what originally PIMPL is). There are no cross-library bridge trees in framework though. It's not required to use them,  it's even advised AGAINST of you to try to use their private classes, but noone forbids you from creating your own bridge or cheshire cat.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

## Introduction

The PIMPL is a private class that contains all of the implementation-specific data of the parent class. Qt provides a PIMPL framework and a set of conventions that need to be followed when using that framework. Qt's PIMPLs can be used in all classes, even those not derived from `QObject`.

The PIMPL needs to be allocated on the heap. In idiomatic C++, we must not manage such storage manually, but use a smart pointer. Either `QScopedPointer` or `std::unique_ptr` work for this purpose. Thus, a minimal pimpl-based interface, not derived from `QObject`, might look like:

```
// Foo.h
#include <QScopedPointer>
class FooPrivate; ///< The PIMPL class for Foo
class Foo {
  QScopedPointer<FooPrivate> const d_ptr;
public:
  Foo();
  ~Foo();
};
```

The destructor's declaration is necessary, since the scoped pointer's destructor needs to destruct an instance of the PIMPL. The destructor must be generated in the implementation file, where the `FooPrivate` class lives:

```
// Foo.cpp
class FooPrivate { };
Foo::Foo() : d_ptr(new FooPrivate) {}
Foo::~Foo() {}
```

See also:

- [A deeper exposition of the idiom](http://marcmutz.wordpress.com/translated-articles/pimp-my-pimpl/).
- [Gotchas and pitfalls of PIMPL](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill05.htm).

## The Interface

We'll now explain the PIMPL-based `CoordinateDialog` interface in the question.

Qt provides several macros and implementation helpers that reduce the drudgery of PIMPLs.   The implementation expects us to follow these rules:

- The PIMPL for a class `Foo` is named `FooPrivate`.
- The PIMPL is forward-declared along the declaration of the `Foo` class in the interface (header) file.

### The Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE Macro

The `Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE` macro must be put in the `private` section of the class's declaration. It takes the interface class's name as a parameter. It declares two inline implementations of the `d_func()` helper method. That method returns the PIMPL pointer with proper constness. When used in const methods, it returns a pointer to a *const* PIMPL. In non-const methods, it returns a pointer to a non-const PIMPL. It also provides a pimpl of correct type in derived classes. It follows that all access to the pimpl from within the implementation is to be done using `d_func()` and *not* through `d_ptr`. Usually we'd use the `Q_D` macro, described in the Implementation section below.

The macro comes in two flavors:

```
Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE(Class)   // assumes that the PIMPL pointer is named d_ptr
Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE_D(Dptr, Class) // takes the PIMPL pointer name explicitly
```

In our case, `Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE(CoordinateDialog)` is equivalent to `Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE_D(d_ptr, CoordinateDialog)`.

### The Q_PRIVATE_SLOT Macro

This macro is only needed for Qt 4 compatibility, or when targeting non-C++11 compilers. For Qt 5, C++11 code, it is unnecessary, as we can connect functors to signals and there's no need for explicit private slots.

We sometimes need for a `QObject` to have private slots for internal use. Such slots would pollute the interface's private section. Since the information about slots is only relevant to the moc code generator, we can, instead, use the `Q_PRIVATE_SLOT` macro to tell moc that a given slot is to be invoked through the `d_func()` pointer, instead of through `this`.

The syntax expected by moc in the `Q_PRIVATE_SLOT` is:

```
Q_PRIVATE_SLOT(instance_pointer, method signature)
```

In our case:

```
Q_PRIVATE_SLOT(d_func(), void onAccepted())
```

This effectively declares an `onAccepted` slot on the `CoordinateDialog` class. The moc generates the following code to invoke the slot:

```
d_func()->onAccepted()
```

The macro itself has an empty expansion - it only provides information to moc.

Our interface class is thus expanded as follows:

```
class CoordinateDialog : public QDialog
{
  Q_OBJECT /* We don't expand it here as it's off-topic. */
  // Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE(CoordinateDialog)
  inline CoordinateDialogPrivate* d_func() { 
    return reinterpret_cast<CoordinateDialogPrivate *>(qGetPtrHelper(d_ptr));
  }
  inline const CoordinateDialogPrivate* d_func() const { 
    return reinterpret_cast<const CoordinateDialogPrivate *>(qGetPtrHelper(d_ptr));
  }
  friend class CoordinateDialogPrivate;
  // Q_PRIVATE_SLOT(d_func(), void onAccepted())
  // (empty)
  QScopedPointer<CoordinateDialogPrivate> const d_ptr;
public:
  [...]
};
```

When using this macro, you must include the moc-generated code in a place where the private class is fully defined. In our case, this means that the `CoordinateDialog.cpp` file should **end** with:

```
#include "moc_CoordinateDialog.cpp"
```

### Gotchas

- All of the `Q_` macros that are to be used in a class declaration already include a semicolon. No explicit semicolons are needed after `Q_`:

  ```
    // correct                       // verbose, has double semicolons
    class Foo : public QObject {     class Foo : public QObject {
      Q_OBJECT                         Q_OBJECT;
      Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE(...)           Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE(...);
      ...                              ...
    };                               };
  ```
- The PIMPL *must not* be a private class within `Foo` itself:

  ```
    // correct                  // wrong
    class FooPrivate;           class Foo {
    class Foo {                   class FooPrivate;
      ...                         ...
    };                          };
  ```
- The first section after the opening brace in a class declaration is private by default. Thus the following are equivalent:

  ```
    // less wordy, preferred    // verbose
    class Foo {                 class Foo {              
      int privateMember;        private:
                                  int privateMember;
    };                          };
  ```
- The `Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE` expects the interface class's name, not the PIMPL's name:

  ```
    // correct                  // wrong
    class Foo {                 class Foo {
      Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE(Foo)      Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE(FooPrivate)
      ...                         ...
    };                          };
  ```
- The PIMPL pointer should be const for non-copyable/non-assignable classes such as `QObject`. It can be non-const when implementing copyable classes.
- Since the PIMPL is an internal implementation detail, its size is not available at the site where the interface is used. The temptation to use placement new and the [Fast Pimpl](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/028.htm) idiom should be resisted as it provides no benefits for anything but a class that doesn't allocate memory at all.

## The Implementation

The PIMPL has to be defined in the implementation file. If it is large, it can also be defined in a private header, customarily named `foo_p.h` for a class whose interface is in `foo.h`.

The PIMPL, at a minimum, is merely a carrier of the main class's data. It only needs a constructor and no other methods. In our case, it also needs to store the pointer to the main class, as we'll want to emit a signal from the main class. Thus:

```
// CordinateDialog.cpp
#include <QFormLayout>
#include <QDoubleSpinBox>
#include <QDialogButtonBox>

class CoordinateDialogPrivate {
  Q_DISABLE_COPY(CoordinateDialogPrivate)
  Q_DECLARE_PUBLIC(CoordinateDialog)
  CoordinateDialog * const q_ptr;
  QFormLayout layout;
  QDoubleSpinBox x, y, z;
  QDialogButtonBox buttons;
  QVector3D coordinates;
  void onAccepted();
  CoordinateDialogPrivate(CoordinateDialog*);
};
```

The PIMPL is not copyable. Since we use non-copyable members, any attempt to copy or assign to the PIMPL would be caught by the compiler. Generally, it's best to explicitly disable the copy functionality by using `Q_DISABLE_COPY`.

The `Q_DECLARE_PUBLIC` macro works similarly to `Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE`. It is described later in this section.

We pass the pointer to the dialog into the constructor, allowing us to initialize the layout on the dialog. We also connect the `QDialog`'s accepted signal to the internal `onAccepted` slot.

```
CoordinateDialogPrivate::CoordinateDialogPrivate(CoordinateDialog * dialog) :
  q_ptr(dialog),
  layout(dialog),
  buttons(QDialogButtonBox::Ok | QDialogButtonBox::Cancel)
{
  layout.addRow("X", &x);
  layout.addRow("Y", &y);
  layout.addRow("Z", &z);
  layout.addRow(&buttons);
  dialog->connect(&buttons, SIGNAL(accepted()), SLOT(accept()));
  dialog->connect(&buttons, SIGNAL(rejected()), SLOT(reject()));
#if QT_VERSION <= QT_VERSION_CHECK(5,0,0)
  this->connect(dialog, SIGNAL(accepted()), SLOT(onAccepted()));
#else
  QObject::connect(dialog, &QDialog::accepted, [this]{ onAccepted(); });
#endif
}
```

The `onAccepted()` PIMPL method needs to be exposed as a slot in Qt 4/non-C++11 projects. For Qt 5 and C++11, this is no longer necessary.

Upon the acceptance of the dialog, we capture the coordinates and emit the `acceptedCoordinates` signal. That's why we need the public pointer:

```
void CoordinateDialogPrivate::onAccepted() {
  Q_Q(CoordinateDialog);
  coordinates.setX(x.value());
  coordinates.setY(y.value());
  coordinates.setZ(z.value());
  emit q->acceptedCoordinates(coordinates);
}
```

The `Q_Q` macro declares a local `CoordinateDialog * const q` variable. It is described later in this section.

The public part of the implementation constructs the PIMPL and exposes its properties:

```
CoordinateDialog::CoordinateDialog(QWidget * parent, Qt::WindowFlags flags) :
  QDialog(parent, flags),
  d_ptr(new CoordinateDialogPrivate(this))
{}

QVector3D CoordinateDialog::coordinates() const {
  Q_D(const CoordinateDialog);
  return d->coordinates;
}

CoordinateDialog::~CoordinateDialog() {}
```

The `Q_D` macro declares a local `CoordinateDialogPrivate * const d` variable. It is described below.

### The Q_D Macro

To access the PIMPL in an *interface* method, we can use the `Q_D` macro, passing it the name of the interface class.

```
void Class::foo() /* non-const */ {
  Q_D(Class);    /* needs a semicolon! */
  // expands to
  ClassPrivate * const d = d_func();
  ...
```

To access the PIMPL in a *const interface* method, we need to prepend the class name with the `const` keyword:

```
void Class::bar() const {
  Q_D(const Class);
  // expands to
  const ClassPrivate * const d = d_func();
  ...
```

### The Q_Q Macro

To access the interface instance from a *non-const PIMPL* method, we can use the `Q_Q` macro, passing it the name of the interface class.

```
void ClassPrivate::foo() /* non-const*/ {
  Q_Q(Class);   /* needs a semicolon! */
  // expands to
  Class * const q = q_func();
  ...
```

To access the interface instance in a *const PIMPL* method, we prepend the class name with the `const` keyword, just as we did for the `Q_D` macro:

```
void ClassPrivate::foo() const {
  Q_Q(const Class);   /* needs a semicolon! */
  // expands to
  const Class * const q = q_func();
  ...
```

### The Q_DECLARE_PUBLIC Macro

This macro is optional and is used to allow access to the *interface* from the PIMPL. It is typically used if the PIMPL's methods need to manipulate the interface's base class, or emit its signals. The equivalent  `Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE` macro was used to allow access to the *PIMPL* from the interface.

The macro takes the interface class's name as a parameter. It declares two inline implementations of the `q_func()` helper method. That method returns the interface pointer with proper constness. When used in const methods, it returns a pointer to a *const* interface. In non-const methods, it returns a pointer to a non-const interface. It also provides the interface of correct type in derived classes. It follows that all access to the interface from within the PIMPL is to be done using `q_func()` and **not through `q_ptr`. Usually we'd use the `Q_Q` macro, described above.

The macro expects the pointer to the interface to be named `q_ptr`. There is no two-argument variant of this macro that would allow to choose a different name for the interface pointer (as was the case for `Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE`).

The macro expands as follows:

```
class CoordinateDialogPrivate {
  //Q_DECLARE_PUBLIC(CoordinateDialog)
  inline CoordinateDialog* q_func() {
    return static_cast<CoordinateDialog*>(q_ptr);
  }
  inline const CoordinateDialog* q_func() const {
    return static_cast<const CoordinateDialog*>(q_ptr);
  }
  friend class CoordinateDialog;
  //
  CoordinateDialog * const q_ptr;
  ...
};
```

### The Q_DISABLE_COPY Macro

This macro deletes the copy constructor and the assignment operator. It *must* appear in the private section of the PIMPL.

### Common Gotchas

- The *interface* header for a given class must be the first header to be included in the implementation file. This forces the header to be self-contained and not dependent on declarations that happen to be included in the implementation. If it isn't so, the implementation will fail to compile, allowing you to fix the interface to make it self-sufficient.

  ```
    // correct                   // error prone
    // Foo.cpp                   // Foo.cpp

    #include "Foo.h"             #include <SomethingElse>
    #include <SomethingElse>     #include "Foo.h"
                                 // Now "Foo.h" can depend on SomethingElse without
                                 // us being aware of the fact.
  ```
- The `Q_DISABLE_COPY` macro must appear in the private section of the PIMPL

  ```
    // correct                    // wrong
    // Foo.cpp                    // Foo.cpp

    class FooPrivate {            class FooPrivate {
      Q_DISABLE_COPY(FooPrivate)  public:
      ...                           Q_DISABLE_COPY(FooPrivate)
    };                               ...
                                  };
  ```

## PIMPL And Non-QObject Copyable Classes

The PIMPL idiom allows one to implement copyable, copy- and move- constructible, assignable object. The assignment is done through the [copy-and-swap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) idiom, preventing code duplication. The PIMPL pointer must not be const, of course.

In C++11, we need to heed the [Rule of Four](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4782757/1329652), and provide *all* of the following: the copy constructor, move constructor, assignment operator, and destructor. And the free-standing `swap` function to implement it all, of course†.

We'll illustrate this using a rather useless, but nevertheless correct example.

#### Interface

```
// Integer.h
#include <algorithm>
#include <QScopedPointer>

class IntegerPrivate;
class Integer {
   Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE(Integer)
   QScopedPointer<IntegerPrivate> d_ptr;
public:
   Integer();
   Integer(int);
   Integer(const Integer & other);
   Integer(Integer && other);
   operator int&();
   operator int() const;
   Integer & operator=(Integer other);
   friend void swap(Integer& first, Integer& second) /* nothrow */;
   ~Integer();
};
```

For performance, the move constructor and the assignment operator should be defined in the interface (header) file. They don't need to access the PIMPL directly:

```
Integer::Integer(Integer && other) : Integer() {
   swap(*this, other);
}

Integer & Integer::operator=(Integer other) {
   swap(*this, other);
   return *this;
}
```

All of those use the `swap` freestanding function, which we must define in the interface as well. Note that it is

```
void swap(Integer& first, Integer& second) /* nothrow */ {
   using std::swap;
   swap(first.d_ptr, second.d_ptr);
}
```

#### Implementation

This is rather straightforward. We don't need access to the interface from the PIMPL, thus `Q_DECLARE_PUBLIC` and `q_ptr` are absent.

```
// Integer.cpp
#include "Integer.h"

class IntegerPrivate {
public:
   int value;
   IntegerPrivate(int i) : value(i) {}
};

Integer::Integer() : d_ptr(new IntegerPrivate(0)) {}
Integer::Integer(int i) : d_ptr(new IntegerPrivate(i)) {}
Integer::Integer(const Integer &other) :
   d_ptr(new IntegerPrivate(other.d_func()->value)) {}
Integer::operator int&() { return d_func()->value; }
Integer::operator int() const { return d_func()->value; }
Integer::~Integer() {}
```

†Per [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom): There are other claims that we should specialize `std::swap` for our type, provide an in-class `swap` along-side a free-function `swap`, etc. But this is all unnecessary: any proper use of `swap` will be through an unqualified call, and our function will be found through [ADL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup). One function will do.

Comment: For anyone else like me that had to look up "PIMPL" = **P**ointer to **IMPL**ementation

Comment: In the Integer example I noticed that the copy constructor makes a duplicate of the praivate object instead of simply pointing to the existing one. Isn't the whole point to "share" private data between interfaces?

Comment: @LennartRolland PIMPL and shared data are two separate concerns. You can use PIMPL to implement a class with shared data, but you don't have to. Sharing private data is fraught with peril, that Qt does it with abandon is fallout from pre-C++11.

Comment: I don't understand why you have to declare de destructor. The `QScopedPointer` destructor must be called automatically, and the default destructor is equivalent to an empty one, as you have written.

Comment: @Peregring-lk It's not about the declaration of a destructor, it's about its definition. The `QScopedPointer` has to destruct the PIMPL. To do so, it needs to have the PIMPL fully defined. And that is only the case in the `.cpp` file, not in the header. Thus you must *define* the destructor in the `.cpp` file. The users of the class only have headers available and there, the compiler is unable to generate the code for the smart pointer. There are smart pointers that cope with it by capturing the destructor where a full definition exists. `std::unique_ptr` is one such example.

Comment: @KubaOber I have never thought about it, and makes sense. So, if I have understood you (the Qt docs says additionally that the constructors or destructor of a PIMPL/QScopedPointer owner must not be `inline` for forward declared classes), you must declare the destructor to force the compiler to link the destructor instead of generating code there. So, the smart pointer destructor is never called from a "user" translation unit, and thus, the required code never generated, but only in the `cpp`.