# PyQt Threading Attributee Error

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, qthread

I'm new on PyQt and i just want to do QThreading.
But i'm getting error : AttributeError: 'myThread' object has no attribute 'ui'

My code:

```
from time import sleep

from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from takipSistemi import Ui_MainWindow



class anaPencere(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.ui=Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.thread = myThread()
        self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(0,  0, QTableWidgetItem("hi!"))
        self.thread.start()    

class myThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QThread.__init__(self,parent)
        self.exiting = False

    def __del__(self):
        self.exiting = True
        self.wait()

    def run(self):
        #error
        self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(0 , 0, QTableWidgetItem('hi there!'))

uyg=QApplication([])
pencere=anaPencere()
pencere.show()
uyg.exec_()
```

How can i attribute ui to myThread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of the two classes `anaPencere`and `myThread` only the first one has the attribute `self.ui = ...` assigned. Because `myThread` has no attribute `ui` you get the error when calling `self.ui.tableWidget...`.

To fix this you have several options. One would be to pass a reference of the class `anaPencere` to its thread class:

```
class anaPencere(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.thread = myThread(self)
        self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(0,  0, QTableWidgetItem("hi!"))
        self.thread.start()


class myThread(QThread):

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.exiting = False

    def __del__(self):
        self.exiting = True
        self.wait()

    def run(self):
        self.parent().ui.tableWidget.setItem(0 , 0, QTableWidgetItem('hi there!'))
```

If this approach (using `anaPencere` as the `parent` of `QThread`) you could also pass `self` as a second argument in `myThread`'s `__init__`.

On a second note: you nearly always want to pass a parent object to each new created object that derives from Qt's `QObject` (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30354276/6205205)