# Any ideas on why Qt Designer passes MainWindow to QtWidget?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

`self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)`
Why  is MainWindow passed to QtWidget?
It was generate using QtDesigner btw..
Any ideas?

Comment: Because it sets `MainWindow` as the parent of `self.centralwidget`?

Comment: This might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30354166/what-is-parent-for-in-qt

Comment: If you look at the [QWidget()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#QWidget) constructor in the documentation, you'll see that the first (keyworded, as in *optional*) argument is the *parent* widget. Creating a widget with a parent ensures that it will always be a child of *that* parent and will only be drawn (*clipped*) inside that parent's coordinate system (although this might not happen for specific cases, such as QDialog). If no parent is given, the widget becomes a *top level* widget (it has its own window). Also read [Object Tree and Ownership](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html).

Comment: Just in case, a very important aspect to remember: reading `pyuic` generated files is educational, as it allows to better understand how widgets *can be* created in PyQt. But, please, keep in mind that those files should never, ***EVER*** be modified (if not ***exclusively*** for learning purposes), nor you should try to mimic their behavior or subclass their classes. Those files should always be imported *as they are* in the main scripts of your program, as explained in the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).