# Qt5: How to wait for a signal in a thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, timer, wait

Probably the title question is not very explicit. I am using Qt5 on Windows7.

In a thread (QThread) at some point, in the `"process()"` function/method, I must wait for the `"encrypted()"` SIGNAL belonging to a QSslSocket I am using in this thread. Also I suppose I should use a QTimer and wait for a `"timeout()"` SIGNAL in order to avoid getting blocked in an infinite loop...
What I have now is:

```
// start processing data
void Worker::process()
{
    status = 0;
    connect(sslSocket, SIGNAL(encrypted()), this, SLOT(encryptionStarted()));
    QTimer timer;
    connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(timerTimeout()));
    timer.start(10000);
    while(status == 0)
    {
        QThread::msleep(5);
    }

    qDebug("Ok, exited loop!");

    // other_things here
    // .................
    // end other_things

    emit finished();
}

// slot (for timer)
void Worker::timerTimeout()
{
    status = 1;
}

// slot (for SSL socket encryption ready)
void Worker::encryptionStarted()
{
    status = 2;
}
```

Well, obviously it doesn't work. It stays in that while-loop forever...
So, the question is: Is there a way to solve this problem? How can I wait for that `"encrypted()"` SIGNAL but not more than - let's say 10 seconds - in order to avoid getting stuck in that waiting-loop/thread?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can use a local event loop to wait for the signal to be emitted :

```
QTimer timer;
timer.setSingleShot(true);
QEventLoop loop;
connect( sslSocket, &QSslSocket::encrypted, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit );
connect( &timer, &QTimer::timeout, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit );
timer.start(msTimeout);
loop.exec();

if(timer.isActive())
    qDebug("encrypted");
else
    qDebug("timeout");
```

Here it waits until `encrypted` is emitted or the the timeout reaches.

Comment: Very good idea. I tested it (with some modifications to suit my code & purpose) and it works ok. I voted up of course:)

Comment: Simple and concise. Bravo.

Comment: Using event-loop this way will result in "busy wait", right?

Comment: @harihardik No. While waiting all events in the main thread are processed and GUI works normal. But this kind of coding is not good practice and it' s recommended to use async methods.

Comment: How to catch signal arguments in this fashion? For example if the encrypted signal had a QVariant payload?

Comment: @Pa_ You can simply connect the `encrypted` signal to a lambda with the argument and call `quit` method of event loop in the lambda (a reference to the event loop object should be captured in lambda).

Comment: Do I need to worry about the `disconnect` issue? For both `lambda `and `quit` ways.

Answer (score 11):

Starting in Qt 5.0, [QSignalSpy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalspy.html#wait) offers a wait method. You hook it up to a signal and wait() will block until the signal fires.

```
QSignalSpy spy(SIGNAL(encrypted()));
spy.wait(5000);  //wait until signal fires or 5 second timeout expires
```

Comment: Note that this class is contained in the Qt::Test module.

Answer (score 9):

In asynchronous programming, the "wait for" is considered an anti-pattern. Instead of waiting for things, design the code to react to a condition becoming fulfilled. E.g., connect the code to a signal.

One way of implementing this is to slice your actions into separate states, and do some work when each of the states is entered. Of course if the amount of work is non-trivial, use a separate slot instead of a lambda to keep things readable.

Note the absence of explicit memory management. Use of owning pointers to Qt classes is a premature optimization and should be avoided where unnecessary. The objects can be direct members of the `Worker` (or its [PIMPL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25250171/1329652)).

The sub-objects must be all a part of the ownership hierarchy that has `Worker` at the root. That way, you can safely move the `Worker` instance to another thread, and the objects it uses will follow it. Of course you could also instantiate the `Worker` in the correct thread - there's a simple [idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21653558/1329652) for that. The thread's event dispatcher owns the worker, thus when the thread's event loop quits (i.e. after invoking `QThread::quit()`), the worker will be automatically disposed and no resources will leak.

```
template <typename Obj>
void instantiateInThread(QThread * thread) {
  Q_ASSERT(thread);
  QObject * dispatcher = thread->eventDispatcher();
  Q_ASSERT(dispatcher); // the thread must have an event loop
  QTimer::singleShot(0, dispatcher, [dispatcher](){
    // this happens in the given thread
    new Obj(dispatcher);
  });
}
```

The Worker's implementation:

```
class Worker : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  QSslSocket sslSocket;
  QTimer timer;
  QStateMachine machine;
  QState s1, s2, s3;
  Q_SIGNAL void finished();
public:
  explicit Worker(QObject * parent = {}) : QObject(parent),
    sslSocket(this), timer(this), machine(this),
    s1(&machine), s2(&machine), s3(&machine) {
    timer.setSingleShot(true);
    s1.addTransition(&sslSocket, SIGNAL(encrypted()), &s2);
    s1.addTransition(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), &s3);
    connect(&s1, &QState::entered, [this]{
      // connect the socket here
      ...
      timer.start(10000);
    });
    connect(&s2, &QState::entered, [this]{
      // other_things here
      ...
      // end other_things
      emit finished();
    });
    machine.setInitialState(&s1);
    machine.start();
  }
};
```

Then:

```
void waitForEventDispatcher(QThread * thread) {
  while (thread->isRunning() && !thread->eventDispatcher())
    QThread::yieldCurrentThread();
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  QCoreApplication app{argc, argv};
  struct _ : QThread { ~Thread() { quit(); wait(); } thread;
  thread.start();
  waitForEventDispatcher(&thread);
  instantiateInThread<Worker>(&myThread);
  ...
  return app.exec();
}
```

Note that connecting to `QThread::started()` would be racy: the event dispatcher doesn't exist until some code within `QThread::run()` had a chance to execute. Thus we have to wait for the thread to get there by yielding - this is very likely to get the worker thread to progress far enough within one or two yields. Thus it won't waste much time.

Comment: Very interesting approach! I will test it tomorrow (after adapting it to fit my code) and I will try to provide the related feedback :)  Hmmm, just great to have a status-machine inside a thread! Sorry I am so enthusiastic, but I am novice in Qt, so each time I see something new (for me) I realize how huge possibilities Qt/C++ can offer...!  I wish I can see more examples like this! What can I say? Bravo, excellent idea!

Comment: Can you expand on this a bit more: "Note the absence of explicit memory management. Use of owning pointers to Qt classes is a premature optimization and should be avoided where unnecessary."

Comment: @Mitch Manual memory management is where you `new` something and assign it to a raw C pointer, and then have to manually delete it. The code doesn't even *have* explicit memory allocation with `new`, but if it had them, the results would be immediately either assigned to smart pointers or made children in a `QObject` tree. Note that a `QObject` acts as a smart pointer collection for other `QObject`s.

Comment: @Mitch Lots of bad Qt examples, including those bundled with Qt, use completely unnecessary explicit heap allocations. Since *every* significant Qt class allocates a [PIMPL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25250171/how-to-use-the-qts-pimpl-idiom/25250172#25250172), you're doubling the number of allocations by putting what amounts to PIMPL pointers on the heap. A `QObject` and `QWidget` have the size of ~4-6 pointers even if their PIMPL is two orders of magnitude larger. If you add children in constructors, simply add them as regular (non-pointer) members to the class or its PIMPL.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure whether you meant `QObject`-based memory management or smart pointers.

Comment: @Mitch Basically, with modern C++, you're supposed to let the compiler and the libraries do the memory management for you. If you do it manually and it's not wrapped in usual RAII facades, you're doing it wrong :)

Comment: On StackOverflow, not answering the asked question is an anti-pattern. Lacking context, one should give benefit of the doubt and not assume that ignorance somehow bestows insight. More to the point, the if the question asked is indeed an anti-pattern, then `pthread_wait_cond` must necessarily also be an anti-pattern!

Comment: @Cuadue *pthread_wait_cond must necessarily also be an anti-pattern* Who said it isn't? It's an API meant to be used by libraries as a fast building block. It's not something anyone should be calling directly since they invariably waste a thread that should be doing stuff. Various event queues solve this well, and reinventing the wheel is an antipattern - and oh so pervasive.

Comment: Nobody appointed you an authority on what is and what is not an antipattern. Let's all please try giving benefit of the doubt, rather than assume the asker was incompetent.

Answer (score 4):

I had some time these days and I did some investigation...
Well, I browsed "http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsslsocket.html" and found this:

```
bool QSslSocket::waitForEncrypted(int msecs = 30000)
```

To my real shame, I didn't noticed it before... :(
Definitely need to buy some glasses (*unfortunately*, it's not a joke!)
I am willing to modify my code accordingly in order to test it (on Monday @ office).
Pretty much chances that it'll work.
[**Late edit**]:
Yes, this is the solution I implemented in my final code and it works well, so I decided to share :)

Answer (score 0):

QSignalSpy is the most clean way

To see the how you can take a look to this https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsignalspy.html

Comment: showing an example could improve the long-term value of this post.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).