# Qt5: How to wait for a signal (with filter) in a thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, wait, signals-slots

I have read the post [how-to-wait-for-a-signal-in-a-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31358646/qt5-how-to-wait-for-a-signal-in-a-thread), but still have some confusions:

What if I want to wait a signal with arguments, and filter the incoming signals based on some specific conditions?
Suppose we have `signal: triggered(int i)`

```
QTimer timer;
timer.setSingleShot(true);
QEventLoop loop;
connect( this, &MyClass::triggered, &loop, [&](int i) {
    // only 123 would stop the event loop, otherwise keep waiting until timeout
    if (i == 123)  
        loop.quit();
} );
connect( &timer, &QTimer::timeout, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit );
timer.start(msTimeout);
loop.exec();

if(timer.isActive())
    qDebug("Got 123! It may not be carried by the first incoming signal.");
else
    qDebug("timeout");
```

Questions:

- For the first `connect`, which connected to a lambda, is the third argument `&loop` necessary?
- For the first `connect`, should I `disconnect` it somewhere?
- I saw some comments mentioned the inner `QEventLoop` should be used very careful, why? Am I doing it in the correct manner?
- Can `QSignalSpy` class achieve this?
- Is it possible to rewrite this into a reuseable header template? e.g.`waitForTimeout(QObject* sender, Func1 signal, Func2 predicate, int msec)`

Comment: "is the third argument `&loop` necessary?" Yes, it is prudent. This argument is a `QObject*`; the purpose of it is to have Qt automatically disconnect the signal if and when this object is deleted (it's assumed that the lambda is related to that object in some way). In your example, suppose the timeout occurs, the loop exits, and since it's a local variable on the stack, `loop` object is destroyed. If you didn't specify `&loop` parameter to the first `connect`, that signal would still remain connected, with the lambda holding a dangling reference. If the signal actually fires later, boom!

Comment: "For the first connect, should I disconnect it somewhere?" If you do pass `&loop` argument, the signal will be automatically disconnected when `loop` goes out of scope. If you don't, then yes, you probably should, or else like I said the signal would fire and try to access a dangling reference. However, without `&loop` parameter, you can't even disconnect this particular connection, since you can't identify it. You'd have to disconnect all connections to this signal, which of course may break things if someone else is also listening to it.

Comment: `QSignalSpy` is meant for testing. I'm not sure how it's supposed to help here. I'm not even sure what "this" is in "achieve this". What problem still remains to be solved?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you for your explanation on the importance of the `&loop` in the first `connect`. For your last comment, there's a function [wait](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalspy.html#wait), which can be used for signal waiting. The "this" is meant for the whole implementation, dropping all the existing code above and rewrite the "wait for a signal which carrying a specific argument" with `QSignalSpy.wait`