# Qt Directx rendering

Tags: c++, qt, directx

I'm rendering in Qt widget by DirectX.
I disabled qt paint engine

```
QPaintEngine *paintEngine() const { return NULL; }
```

but sometimes I want to enable qt paint and disable directX rendering.
I'm disabling DirectX rendering, but how can I enable Qt paintEngine?

Answer (score 1):

The possible solutions include:

1. Use a `QWindow`, and then switch rendering between [raster][0] and DirectX.
2. Use a DirectX-rendered `QWindow` or `QWidget`, and render the optional content to a `QImage`. You can use that image as a texture and easily overlay it over the DirectX-rendered content.
3. A quick workaround with little code changes would be to re-create the widget each time the rendering mode changes. This could be implemented very cleanly by having the state of the widget reside in a [PIMPL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25250172/1329652). See the example below.

```
class MyWidgetPrivate {
public:
  bool qtRendering;
  // your data members etc.
  MyWidgetPrivate(bool qtRendering) :
    qtRendering(qtRendering)
  {}
};

class MyWidget : public QWidget {
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE(MyWidget)
  QScopedPointer<MyWidgetPrivate> const d_ptr;

  QPaintEngine *paintEngine() const {
    Q_D(const MyWidget);
    return d->qtRendering ? QWidget::paintEngine() : nullptr;
  }

  MyWidget(QScopedPointer<MyWidgetPrivate> & data, QWidget * parent, bool qtRendering) :
    QWidget(parent),
    d_ptr(data.take())
  {
     d_ptr->qtRendering = qtRendering;
  }
public:
  MyWidget(QWidget * parent, bool qtRendering) :
    QWidget(parent),
    d_ptr(new MyWidgetPrivate(qtRendering))
  {}

  void setQtRendering(bool qtRendering) {
    if (qtRendering == d_ptr->qtRendering) return;
    auto geom = geometry();
    auto parent = this->parentWidget();
    auto & d = const_cast<QScopedPointer<MyWidgetPrivate>&>(d_ptr);
    QScopedPointer<MyWidgetPrivate> pimpl(d.take());
    this->~MyWidget(); // destroy in place
    new (this) MyWidget(pimpl, parent, qtRendering); // reconstruct in place
    setGeometry(geom);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

QWidget::setAttribute(Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent, false);

to reenable Qt background drawing on your widget.

Comment: This one will have issues with aero being switched on.

Comment: can you provide reference? I'm quite curious to know what kind of issues this would create.

Comment: I do not have reference. While playing with directx rendering inside Qt application touching Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent led to some artifacts.