# Multiple definition error when creating Private subclass in Qt Pimpl class

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, pimpl-idiom

I have been trying to implement a Pimpl class, following the instructions on [this Qt wiki page](https://wiki.qt.io/D-Pointer), in which the private class inherits from another private base class.

Here is a basic example:

### Base class

#### Header

```
// gadget.h 
#ifndef GADGET_H
#define GADGET_H

#include <QWidget>

class GadgetPrivate;

class Gadget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Gadget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Gadget();

protected:
    Gadget(GadgetPrivate &d, QWidget *parent = 0);

    GadgetPrivate *d_ptr;

private:
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(Gadget)
    Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE(Gadget)
};

#endif // GADGET_H
```

#### Implementation

```
// gadget.cpp
#include "gadget.h"
#include "gadget_p.h"

Gadget::Gadget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent),
      d_ptr(new GadgetPrivate(this))
{}

Gadget::~Gadget() {}

Gadget::Gadget(GadgetPrivate &d, QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent),
      d_ptr(&d)
{}
```

#### Private class

```
// gadget_p.h
#ifndef GADGET_P_H
#define GADGET_P_H

#include "gadget.h"

class GadgetPrivate
{
    Q_DECLARE_PUBLIC(Gadget)

public:
    GadgetPrivate(Gadget *q);

    Gadget *q_ptr;
};

GadgetPrivate::GadgetPrivate(Gadget *q)
    : q_ptr(q)
{}

#endif // GADGET_P_H
```

### Subclass

#### Header

```
// gizmo.h
#ifndef GIZMO_H
#define GIZMO_H

#include "gadget.h"

class GizmoPrivate;

class Gizmo : public Gadget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Gizmo(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Gizmo();

private:
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(Gizmo)
    Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE(Gizmo)
};

#endif // GIZMO_H
```

#### Implementation

```
// gizmo.cpp
#include "gizmo.h"
#include "gadget_p.h"

class GizmoPrivate : public GadgetPrivate
{
    Q_DECLARE_PUBLIC(Gizmo)

public:
    GizmoPrivate(Gizmo *q);
};

GizmoPrivate::GizmoPrivate(Gizmo *q)
    : GadgetPrivate(q)
{}

Gizmo::Gizmo(QWidget *parent)
    : Gadget(*new GizmoPrivate(this), parent)
{}

Gizmo::~Gizmo() {}
```

I get the following error:

```
 In function `GadgetPrivate::GadgetPrivate(Gadget*)':
 error: multiple definition of `GadgetPrivate::GadgetPrivate(Gadget*)'
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution #1:

Make everything in the private base class inline, i.e., changing this,

```
class GadgetPrivate
{
    Q_DECLARE_PUBLIC(Gadget)

public:
    GadgetPrivate(Gadget *q);

    Gadget *q_ptr;
};

GadgetPrivate::GadgetPrivate(Gadget *q)
    : q_ptr(q)
{
}
```

to,

```
class GadgetPrivate
{
    Q_DECLARE_PUBLIC(Gadget)

public:
    GadgetPrivate(Gadget *q)
        : q_ptr(q)
    {
    }

    Gadget *q_ptr;
};
```

made the code compile.

### Solution #2:

This also seems to work:

#### gadget_p.h

```
class GadgetPrivate
{
    Q_DECLARE_PUBLIC(Gadget)

public:
    GadgetPrivate(Gadget *q);

    Gadget *q_ptr;
};
```

#### gadget.cpp

```
#include "gadget.h"
#include "gadget_p.h"

GadgetPrivate::GadgetPrivate(Gadget *q)
    : q_ptr(q)
{
}

Gadget::Gadget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent),
      d_ptr(new GadgetPrivate(this))
{
}

Gadget::~Gadget()
{
}

Gadget::Gadget(GadgetPrivate *d, QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent),
      d_ptr(d)
{
}
```

Implementation of `GadgetPrivate` has moved to `gadget.cpp`.

Answer (score 0):

This constructor declaration:

```
Gadget(GadgetPrivate &d, QWidget *parent)
```

Requires a reference to `GadgetPrivate`, which at this point is just a forward-declared class. Switch to the parameter type to a pointer and you'll be fine:

```
Gadget(GadgetPrivate *d, QWidget *parent)
```

and:

```
Gadget(GadgetPrivate *d, QWidget *parent)
  : QWidget(parent), d_ptr(d)
  {}
```

Some notes:

- First, use a `QScopedPointer` for your `d_ptr`. This will prevent the memory leak you have from not deleting the `d_ptr`. The `q_ptr` should remain a raw pointer.
- [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25250171/how-to-use-the-qts-pimpl-idiom?rq=1) on the PIMPL idiom is fantastic and includes lots of hints about "gotcha"s and the like.
- Marc Mutz wrote some great articles on Qt and the pimpl idiom. They are worth [checking out](https://marcmutz.wordpress.com/translated-articles/pimp-my-pimpl-%E2%80%94-reloaded/). I linked to part 2 of the articles because it goes into more details of the internals.

Comment: Why doesn't `Gadget(*new GizmoPrivate(this), parent)` correspond to `Gadget(GadgetPrivate &d, QWidget *parent = 0);`?

Comment: @kfsone Duh...it does. I must have looked three times for that signature and didn't see it.

Comment: You are right about the memory leak. I removed the `QScopedPointer` since I wasn't sure if it had anything to do with the error.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but I still get the same compiler error. I think the problem is that `gadget_p.h` is included from both `gizmo.cpp` and `gadget.cpp`. If I make everything inline in the private base class, it works. See my separate answer.

Comment: Separate `cpp` files including the same header should not cause such an error. Is it possible you had an inline *and* out-of-line definition?

Comment: @Jon Harper No, that's not it, but I feel that I have missed something. I also realized that it works if I put the implementation code for GadgetPrivate in `gadget.cpp`. Is that a bad idea?

Comment: No, that is perfectly sound practice. It limits what's included for classes derived from `GadgetPrivate` and thus speeds compile times (which is part of the point of PIMPL).