# what happens if i don't use deletelater for deleting qthread?

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qthread

I'm trying to use Qthread with an object. For this purpose this code is written:

```
QThread *thread1 = new QThread();
serialclass *obje = new serialclass();
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_baglan_clicked()
{
  obje->moveToThread(thread1);
  connect(thread1,SIGNAL(started()),obje,SLOT(baglan()), Qt::UniqueConnection);
  connect(obje,SIGNAL(finished()),thread1,SLOT(quit())); //end of the baglan function finished() signal is emitted.
  thread1->start();
}
```

My code works. But I used quit(), not deletelater(). The button can be pushed a lot of time. First question is, is this method true? My second question is what happens if i push the button a lot of time. Are there a lot of thread? Is every time one thread created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fine. You should understand what you're doing and why: the code and its purpose should come from you and from such understanding.

When you push the button a lot of times, the application might be in one of two states:

1. The thread has already finished: `obje->thread() == nullptr` and you're restarting the thread - it will work fine.
2. The thread is still running: `obje->thread() == thread1` and both `moveToThread` and `thread1->start()` do nothing.

Alas, there's no point in stopping the thread. It has an event loop that is blocked until new events arrive, it's not as if an idle `QThread` is using up any CPU. Starting a thread is expensive: it creates a new native thread. A finished thread ceases to exist: yes, you still have a `QThread`, but that's like having a handle to a closed file. `QThread` is a thread handle, after all.

You should keep your members by value, not by pointer - this avoids the silly premature pessimization of extra indirection via a point. You can set up all the connections ahead of time. You don't need the `on_pushButton_baglan_clicked()` slot: you can connect the pushbutton directly with the `SerialClass` instance. You should also use a `QThread`-derived class that is safely destructible.

Your code can look as follows. The compiler will generate a proper resource-deallocating destructor for you. It's the compiler's job, and it won't ever fail you in that job - whereas a human developer is very prone to failure. Thus you should leverage RAII to your full advantage, as it shifts a menial manual job onto the machine that will do it perfectly and for next to nothing :)

```
// MyWindow.h
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QThread>
#include "SerialClass.h"
#include "ui_MyWindow.h"

class MyWindow : public QMainWindow {
  Q_OBJECT
  class SafeThread : public QThread {
    using QThread::run; // final
  public:
    ~SafeThread() { quit(); wait(); }
  } m_serialThread;
  SerialClass m_serial;
  Ui::MyWindow ui;
public:
  MyWindow(QWidget * parent = nullptr);
};

// MyWindow.cpp
#include "MyWindow.h"

MyWindow::MyWindow(QWidget * parent) :
  QMainWindow{this}
{
  ui.setupUi(this);
  connect(ui.pushButton_baglan, &QPushButton::clicked,
          &m_serial, &SerialClass::baglan);
  m_serial.moveToThread(&m_serialThread);
  m_serialThread.start();
}
```

If you don't want all the implementation details to live in `MyWindow`'s header, you [should use a PIMPL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25250171/1329652).