# Why reinterpret_cast is used in the implementation d_fun() while defining Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE macro

Tags: c++, qt

Qt classes have a `Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE` macro in the public class. The macro reads:

```
#define Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE(Class)\
    inline Class##Private* d_func() {\
        return reinterpret_cast<Class##Private*>(qGetPtrHelper(d_ptr));\
    }\
    inline const Class##Private d_func() const {\
        return reinterpret_cast<const Class##Private *>(qGetPtrHelper(d_ptr));\
    }\
    friend class Class##Private;
```

Here, as per my understanding `Class##Private` will be parent of class of `d_ptr` then why `reinterpret_cast` is used and not `dynamic_cast`?

Comment: If it was a parent class, you wouldn't need a cast at all

Comment: @StoryTeller while correct, please note that the Qt pimpl idiom explicitly cannot assume anything about hiearchies, the macros are API which must work with arbitrary consuming code.

Comment: @user268396, how is my comment in conflict with what you said?

Answer (score 4):

The reasons are:

1. A `dynamic_cast` is not supported in Qt source code, as Qt can be built with RTTI turned off.

   The `dynamic_cast<` string appears in about a dozen locations in non-tests, non-3rdparty Qt 5.7.0 sources, and most of them are essentially bugs/omissions.
2. The macro is used in headers where `Class##Private` is forward-defined. A `static_cast` wouldn't work as the compiler doesn't know that `Class##Private` is derived from the pointed-to type of `d_ptr`.
3. If `Class##Private` wasn't forward-defined, then the correct cast to use would be `static_cast`. A `dynamic_cast` would be a premature pessimization, since the macro is used in a place where `d_ptr`'s pointed-to type is known at compile time, albeit not in the header.

For more details about `Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE`, see also [How to use the Qt's PIMPL idiom?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25250171/1329652).

Comment: @Kuba Ober: Thanks for explaining why `static_cast` wouldn't work as well.

Answer (score 1):

Because `dynamic_cast` requires the class to have at least one `virtual` method (it needs to be polymorphic). Just class inheritance isn't enough for `dynamic_cast` to succeed.

Comment: The PIMPL classes typically must have a virtual destructor, since they will *always* be destroyed via the pointer to the base class. So that's not it. One big reason is that `dynamic_cast` is not supported in Qt source code.  The `dynamic_cast` appears in about a dozen locations in Qt 5.7.0 sources, and all of them are essentially bugs/omissions.