# Qt - Overriding QTreeView::drawBranches()

Tags: c++, qt, overriding, qtreeview

I want to override the function **drawBranches()** in **QTreeView**.
I subclassed the QTreeView class, then I copied **drawBranches()** function from [here](https://github.com/radekp/qt/blob/master/src/gui/itemviews/qtreeview.cpp). Before change anything in this function, I want to ensure that it works first, but build failed with this error:

```
error: 'const QTreeViewPrivate* QTreeView::d_func() const' is private
 inline const Class##Private* d_func() const { return reinterpret_cast<const Class##Private *>(qGetPtrHelper(d_ptr)); } \
```

Here is my code:

```
class MyTreeView : public QTreeView
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyTreeView(QWidget *parent =0) : QTreeView(parent) {}
    void drawBranches(QPainter * painter, const QRect &rect, const 
                        QModelIndex &index)const
    {
        Q_D(const QTreeView);
        const bool reverse = isRightToLeft();
        const int indent = d->indent;
        const int outer = d->rootDecoration ? 0 : 1;
        const int item = d->current;
        const QTreeViewItem &viewItem = d->viewItems.at(item);
        int level = viewItem.level;
        QRect primitive(reverse ? rect.left() : rect.right() + 1, rect.top(), indent, rect.height());

        ....// Moore lines that I copied

            else
                opt.state &= ~QStyle::State_MouseOver;
            style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_IndicatorBranch, &opt, painter, this);
            current = ancestor;
            ancestor = current.parent();
        }
        painter->setBrushOrigin(oldBO);
}
```

};

There is many lines where ***d pointer*** is used and it is private, e.g `d->indent;` .

How can I get a reference to this pointer without violating private role?

**Why I want to override this function**: I want to hide the expand/collapse indicator for all items except those who have level **zero** (height level) and  I guess by overriding this function I can do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to consult the [reference on using Qt PIMPL idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25250171/1329652).

Every `d_func` is private. You need to declare your own. Yours is a special case because you don't derive from `QTreeViewPrivate`, thus the type returned is still `QTreeViewPrivate*`. Qt provides a handy macro that does the work for you:

```
// Interface
#include <QTreeView>

class MyTreeView : public QTreeView
{
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE(QTreeView)
public:
  MyTreeView(QWidget * parent = {}) : QTreeView{parent} {}
protected:
  void drawBranches(QPainter *, const QRect &, const QModelIndex&) const override;
};
```

```
// Implementation
#include <private/qtreeview_p.h>

void MyTreeView::drawBranches(QPainter * painter, const QRect &rect, const 
                              QModelIndex &index)const
{
  Q_D(const QTreeView);
  ...
}
```

Also, instead of copying code from a random repository, you should copy it [from the official mirror](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/5.9/src/widgets/itemviews/qtreeview.cpp#L1801).

Comment: Thanks for response and thanks for the hint: '' from the official mirror ". I have an issue with QT += gui-private that refuse to include <private/qtreeview_p.h> but I guess I can resolve it.

Comment: add QT += widgets-private instead of gui-private get it works