# Cross-platform class with template function

Tags: c++, qt, function, class, templates

I currently have two different headers defining the same class. What changes between them is the functions implementation and a single variable.

**header_linux.h**

```
class Class
{
private:
    QStringList processesList; // Same variable
    pid_t pid; // Different variable

public:
    void fillProcessesList()
    {
            // Different implementation
    }

    void isProcessRunning(QString name)
    {
            // Same implementation
    }

    template<typename T>
    bool readMemory(unsigned long long address, T &destination)
    {
            // Different implementation
    }
```

**header_win32.h**

```
class Class
{
private:
    QStringList processesList; // Same variable
    HANDLE handle; // Different variable

public:
    void fillProcessesList()
    {
            // Different implementation
    }

    void isProcessRunning(QString name)
    {
            // Same implementation
    }

    template<typename T>
    bool readMemory(unsigned long long address, T &destination)
    {
            // Different implementation
    }
```

I would like to have the common variables and functions in a single file.

My idea was to create **header.h** which defines the class and its members, **header.cpp** which implements the common functions and then **header_linux.cpp** and **header_win32.cpp** which implement the OS-specific functions.

However, template functions must be implemented in the header file.

I could check the operating system using a preprocessor macro and according to that use the right implementation, in a single header, but the functions are many and their body is big.

After a lot of research I found the PIMPL idiom, but the implementation seems complicated.

Is there a better way?

Comment: For what it's worth, `Pimpl` was the first thought that sprang to my mind after I read the first few sentences.

Comment: You should wrap your OS specific stuff into a **non** generic function, and interface with that. As far as I know, OS don't do templates

Comment: ***but the implementation seems complicated.*** You must be reading the wrong sources. There is very little complication using PIMPL (at least to me). Although I have been programming since the early 1980s.

Comment: Thank you for the amazingly fast replies! Could you link me a proper example/source on how to use Pimpl?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl

Comment: Qt itself uses PIMPL internally -- see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25250171/how-to-use-the-qts-pimpl-idiom) for details on how you can use PIMPL macros and such built in to Qt.

Comment: It seems like I still have to use this for my template function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115703/storing-c-template-function-definitions-in-a-cpp-file

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question, but it seems to me that you would only need to implement a non-template `readMemory(void *destination, size_t size, uintptr_t address)` for each platform in the .cpp (wrapping `ReadProcessMemory` on Windows and a `read` from `/proc/$pid/mem` on Linux); then the template helper can be implemented in a cross-platform fashion in the header.

Comment: The problem is that I can't implement it in the header, as the private class is abstract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write template implementations in `cpp` files, all you have to do is write an explicit instantiation definition after the template implementation in the `cpp` file.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template#Explicit_instantiation

Example:

**header.h**

```
template <typename T>
bool readMemory(unsigned long long address, T &destination);
```

**implementation.cpp**

```
template <typename T>
bool readMemory(unsigned long long address, T &destination)
{
    // Implementation
}

// Explicit definitions
template bool readMemory<std::string>(unsigned long long address, std::string &destination);
template bool readMemory<int>(unsigned long long address, int &destination);
```

In this example, you can use `readMemory` **only** with `std::string` and `int` template arguments. Therefore, you have to write a definition for every `typename` that will be used in the template, or else you will get a linker error.  This obviously reduces scalability of your solution, but if there will only be a few possible template arguments, then it should be acceptable.

Comment: I solved my problem by using Qt's PIMPL and explicit instantiation for the types I need, which are only two for now.