# Stop QTextCursor::insertText() from modifying QTextDocument scrollbar range

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit, qtextdocument, qtextcursor

I have a `QTextEdit` that contains a `QTextDocument`, which is being programatically edited using the `QTextCursor` interface. The document is being edited with `QTextCursor::insertText()`.

I load the text file being edited in chunks, so the initial size of the `QTextDocument` might only be 20 lines even though the document is 100,000 lines. However, I want the `QTextEdit` scrollbar to reflect the full size of the document instead of just the 20 line document it's currently displaying.

The QTextEdit's scrollbar range is set with `QScrollBar::setMaximum()` which adjusts the scrollbar to the proper size on the initial opening of the file, but when `QTextCursor::insertText()` is called the `QScrollBar`'s range is recalculated.

I've already tried calling `QScrollBar::setMaximum()` after each `QTextCursor::insertText()` event, but it just makes the whole UI jerky and sloppy.

Is there any way to keep the range of the `QScrollBar` while the `QTextDocument` is being modified?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You'd depend on the implementation detail. In [QTextEditPrivate::init()](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qtextedit.cpp.html#_ZN16QTextEditPrivate4initERK7QString), the following connection is made:

```
Q_Q(QTextEdit);
control = new QTextEditControl(q);
...
QObject::connect(control, SIGNAL(documentSizeChanged(QSizeF)), q, SLOT(_q_adjustScrollbars()))
```

Here, `q` is of the type `QTextEdit*` and is the [Q-pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25250172/1329652) to the API object. Thus, you'd need to disconnect this connection, and manage the scroll bars on your own:

```
bool isBaseOf(const QByteArray &className, const QMetaObject *mo) {
  while (mo) {
    if (mo->className() == className)
      return true;
    mo = mo->superClass();
  }
  return false;
}

bool setScrollbarAdjustmentsEnabled(QTextEdit *ed, bool enable) {
  QObject *control = {};
  for (auto *ctl : ed->children()) {
    if (isBaseOf("QWidgetTextControl", ctl->metaObject()) {
      Q_ASSERT(!control);
      control = ctl;
    }
  }
  if (!control)
    return false;
  if (enable)
    return QObject::connect(control, SIGNAL(documentSizeChanged(QSizeF)), ed, SLOT(_q_adjustScrollbars()), Qt::UniqueConnection);
  else
    return QObject::disconnect(control, SIGNAL(documentSizeChanged(QSizeF)), ed, SLOT(_q_adjustScrollbars()));
}
```

Hopefully, this should be enough to prevent `QTextEdit` from interfering with you.