# How can a class be defined in such way that it inherits from QObject as well within a QObject-derived class?

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, qobject

In `class A`, I define a `class B`. I want to hide the implementation of `class B`. The `class B` inherits from `QObject`.

```
// a.h
class A : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit A(QObjcet* parent=nullptr);
private:
    class B;
    QSharedPointer<B> m_impl;
};

//a.cpp
class A::B : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ...
};

A::A(QObject* parent) : 
    QObject(parent),
    m_impl(QSharedPointer<B>(new B()))
{
}
```

But it has errors:

> undefined reference to 'vtable for A::B'
> undefined reference to 'A::B::staticMetaObject'

What causes them, and how can I fix them?

Comment: How do you build your program? Do you remember to run the `moc` tool and build with the auto-generated source files?

Comment: I build my program use QtCreator default tool.

Comment: Aside from a missing `;` and ignoring qt-specifics (which I don't know well), the code is fine and won't produce the error if linked correctly. The vtable fro `A::B` will be generated in `a.cpp`'s translation unit.

Comment: It is also weird that these errors should be possible at all: `A::B` is defined only in the `a.cpp` translation unit. So which other translation unit could possibly be trying to reference its members/vtable? Where does the compiler say these undefined references occur?

Comment: The way it is written now the compilation should already fail if any other translation unit tries to destruct or copy/move an `A`, but still it can't produce the linker error messages.

Comment: My best guess would then be that `Q_OBJECT`/`moc` is responsible for manifesting the issue, but I can't help with that.

Comment: Are you sure `moc` is being run on `a.cpp` (not just the headers) and the resulting code compiled and linked?

Comment: @user17732522  `undefined reference to 'vtable for A::B'` is due to  `QSharedPointer` and `dynamic_cast` use within macro `Q_OBJECT` inside of `A::B`, missing `A::B::metaobject` is defined there too. The code is autogenerated, but it WILL not be generated automatically if class isn't in a header. Otherwise `QObject`s aren't copyable or movable by definition

Comment: In general the title of question doens't match the nature of question, because this is a Qt feature which stands in the way. Not C++. There is no problems in C++ with inheriting a nested class from another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `QObject`-derived class to be  compiled you need an extra unit containing definitions for `Q_OBJECT` macro, generated by meta-object compiler(moc) utility based on conent of the header where class is declared.

Nested classes or classes inherited from multiple `QObject`s are not supported by Qt and may or may not work. Meta-object compiler also isn't designed to be used on .cpp files because of its limitted ability to parse code. By default Qt toolchains do not run `moc` on .cpp files.

You can create an additional compilation step to run `moc` but that's a dirty and oddball solution, you'd better to have a separate, "private" header if your class is derived from `QObject`, hidden in a folder no foreign unit would look up.

```
//impl/a_private.h
class A::B : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ...
};

 //a.cpp
 #include "a.h"
 #include "impl/a_private.h"
 ...
```

This looks like B is meant to be a private ("bridged") class used within A:

```
class B;
QSharedPointer<B> m_impl;
```

In that case you must use Qt's PIMPL aka Cheshire cat pattern, which is a variant of Bridge pattern.

[How to use the Qt's PIMPL idiom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25250171/how-to-use-the-qts-pimpl-idiom)

TLDR: `A::B` would become a `class APrivate` in global namespace