# How to make default constructor defined outside the class noexcept?

Tags: c++, c++11, default-constructor, noexcept

I know that a constructor marked as `=default` will "try" to be `noexcept` whenever possible. However, if I define it **outside** the class, it is not `noexcept` anymore, as you can see from this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

struct Bar
{
    Bar() = default;
    Bar(Bar&&) = default; // noexcept
};

struct Foo
{
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(Foo&&);
};
// moving the definition outside makes it noexcept(false)
Foo::Foo(Foo&&) = default; // not noexcept anymore

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    Bar bar;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    // checks
    std::cout << std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<Bar>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<Foo>::value << std::endl;
}
```

How can I define such a `=default` constructor outside a class and make it `noexcept`? And why is such a constructor `noexcept(false)` if defined outside the class? This issue arises when implementing [PIMPL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972588/is-the-pimpl-idiom-really-used-in-practice) via smart pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules governing the exception specification for your two examples are covered in *§8.4.2/2 **[dcl.fct.def.default]***

> ... If a function is explicitly defaulted on its first declaration,
>   — it is implicitly considered to be `constexpr` if the implicit declaration would be,
>   — **it is implicitly considered to have the same *exception-specification* as if it had been implicitly declared** (15.4), and
>   — ...

`Bar`'s move constructor is `noexcept(true)` because in *§15.4/14 **[except.spec]***

> An implicitly declared special member function (Clause 12) shall have an *exception-specification*. **If `f` is an implicitly declared** default constructor, copy constructor, **move constructor**, destructor, copy assignment operator, or move assignment operator, its implicit *exception-specification* specifies the *type-id* `T` if and only if `T` is allowed by the *exception-specification* of a function directly invoked by `f`'s implicit definition; `f` shall allow all exceptions if any function it directly invokes allows all exceptions, and **`f` shall allow no exceptions
>   if every function it directly invokes allows no exceptions**.

The rules in §8.4.2/2 do not apply to special member functions that have been explicitly defaulted after the initial declaration, except destructors, which are special cased in §12.4/3 to be `noexcept(true)` unless you declare it `noexcept(false)` or the destructors of one of the data members or base classes can throw.

Thus, unless you specify `Foo(Foo&&)` to be `noexcept(true)`, it is assumed to be `noexcept(false)`.

The reason you needed to add the `noexcept` specification to both the declaration and later explicit default declaration is found in *§15.4*

> *3*   Two *exception-specifications* are *compatible* if:
>   — both are non-throwing (see below), regardless of their form,
>   — ...
>   *4*   If any declaration of a function has an *exception-specification* that is not a *noexcept-specification* allowing all exceptions, all declarations, including the definition and any explicit specialization, of that function shall have a compatible *exception-specification*. ...

Comment: In particular, if it's defaulted after its initial declaration, the defaulting can happen in a different TU, so in a TU which only contains the class definition, the compiler has no way of knowing that the function would be defaulted.

Comment: @T.C. this makes perfect sense, I understand now.

Answer (score 4):

I realized now that I can do this, it didn't cross my mind until now:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(Foo&&) noexcept;
};
Foo::Foo(Foo&&) noexcept = default; // now it is noexcept
```

Still the second question *Why is it `noexcept(false)` by default?* applies.