# C++: Can't figure out how to hide implementation details properly

Tags: c++, private, encapsulation, access-protection

I have the following setup:

`foo.h`:

```
class A {
    friend class B;
private:
    A() {}
};

class B {
public:
    void addObject(Object &o); // adds to myMember; A is not exposed!
    void computeResult(Result &r); // uses myMember to compute result
private:
    vector<A> myMember;
};
```

An object of `A` will never be exposed to any program including `foo.h`. The vector with `A`'s is only there to help `B` in its computation adapter role. By making `A`'s constructor private, I thought I could avoid other compilation units from using it, and it seems to work. However, the problem is in

`foo.cpp`

```
void B::computeResult(Result &r) {
    MyCustomStorage<A> storage;
    A *a = storage.allocate(); // error: "A::A() is private"
}
```

where part of `MyCustomStorage` looks like so:

```
template <typename T>
class MyCustomStorage {
    T *allocate() {
        ...
        T *ptr = new T[count]; // error: "A::A() is private"
        ...
    }
};
```

But I thought since `allocate()` is called from a member function, this wouldn´t happen! How could I solve this?

Making `A` a friend to `MyCustomStorage` seems very spaghetti-codish. Making `A` a private nested class of `B` makes all sorts of help-classes in `foo.cpp` fail because "A is private".

So what would be the cleanest way to solve this?

**SOLUTION**

I ended up going with @potatoswatter 's second solution, with these appropriate changes:

`foo.h`

```
class B {
public:
    void addObject(Object &o); // adds to myMember; A is not exposed!
    void computeResult(Result &r); // uses myMember to compute result
private:
    class A {
    private:
        A() {}
    };
    class Helper; // forward declared!
    vector<A> myMember;
};
```

`foo.cpp`

```
class B::Helper {
    int help(A& a) { return 42; } // no problem! Helper is a member of B
}

void B::computeResult(Result &r) {
    MyCustomStorage<A> storage;
    A *a = storage.allocate(); // no problem! A is a member of B
    Helper h;
    h.help(*a); // no problem!
}
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972588/is-the-pimpl-idiom-really-used-in-practice

Comment: Making `B` a friend of `A` seems fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the constructor of `A` that is private, it's the entire class.

The best solution is to create a "private" namespace. C++ doesn't have namespace-level access protection, but it's reasonable to expect that users won't access an unfamiliar namespace.

```
namespace impl {
struct A {
    A() {}
};
}

class B {
public:
    void addObject(Object &o); // adds to myMember; A is not exposed!
    void computeResult(Result &r); // uses myMember to compute result
private:
    vector<impl::A> myMember;
};
```

Another approach is to make `A` a member of `B`. This offers "real" access protection at the expense of deeper nesting. I personally prefer the first solution, and to avoid nested classes.

```
class B {
public:
    void addObject(Object &o); // adds to myMember; A is not exposed!
    void computeResult(Result &r); // uses myMember to compute result
private:
    struct A {
        A() {}
    };

    vector<A> myMember;
};
```

Any helpers that need `A` would then need to be friends. There are various workarounds like nesting `A` in a base class with `protected` access, but really, `namespace impl` offers the least compromises.

Comment: I like the second one more. It is objectively better since it encapsulates `A`, which the first version does not. I wouldn't hope for people not accessing unfamiliar namespaces, `namespace std;` once was unfamiliar and still everyone is `using` it.

Comment: @nwp But namespaces like `std::__1` and `std::__function` are unfamiliar. Large, popular libraries including all standard library implementations, Boost, etc, tend to prefer the first approach, and otherwise do not contort classes for the sake of access protection.

Comment: @potatoswatter I've used the second solution, edited in my first post. I'd love your comments on whether there's the contortion problem mentioned.

Comment: @bombax Sure, that works. If there's any "contortion," it's just that `B` is capturing additional functionality as if it were a namespace. If it becomes a problem, you can always refactor the nested classes out.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, You have a couple options. You can either 1) Use the [Pimpl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60570/why-should-the-pimpl-idiom-be-used) idiom, or, 2) you can use forward declaration.

Pimpl Idiom Example:

```
class B {
public:
    void addObject(Object &o); // adds to myMember; A is not exposed!
    void computeResult(Result &r); // uses myMember to compute result
private:
    class Impl;
    Impl *pimpl;
};
```

And in your *.cpp file, you can define the `Impl` class and use it's guts.

```
class B::Impl {
public:
    std::vector<A> stuff;
}

B::B() : pimpl(new Impl) {
}

B::~B() {
    delete pimpl;
}

void B::AddObject(Object &o) {
    pimpl->stuff.Fx(o);
}
```

You can also use a smart pointer for the Pimpl idiom, I just didn't here for the sake of clarity/brevity.

Forward declaration can also be used if `A` is in the same namespace as `B`

```
class B {
public:
    void addObject(Object &o); // adds to myMember; A is not exposed!
    void computeResult(Result &r); // uses myMember to compute result
private:
    std::vector<class A*> myMember;
};
```

But this idiom is fundamentally different than your requirements and restricts you to using a pointer within your object `myMember`, which you may not want to do. Inline defining `class A*` is also a non-standard forward-declarative approach. Of course, use of smart pointers would reduce the possibility of memory-leaks at this location.

Comment: `vector<class A*>` is functionally different from `vector<A>`, and it's a memory leak prone anti-pattern. `vector<class A>` with incomplete `class A` will in practice work, and it's slated for standardization, but it's not yet officially blessed.

Comment: @Potatoswatter I made note that `vector<class A*>` is fundamentally different. I will add caveat to the non-standard forward-declaration approach. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: He can use partial specialization with `std::unique_ptr` in order to use pimpl idiom and avoid memory leaks that can be appear with raw pointers.