# How to prevent impl details from being in the header file when a global function needs a pointer to the impl?

Tags: c++, oop, encapsulation, pimpl-idiom, data-hiding

I'm using the [pimpl idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972588/is-the-pimpl-idiom-really-used-in-practice) heavily in my code, mostly to reduce compilation time.

I have a situation where I'm calling into a C library. I have a C++ wrapper class which has its interface, and the gory details are all in the `impl`, of course:

```
class some_class {
public:
    void some_init();
    ...
private:
    class impl;
    std::unique_ptr<impl> m_pimpl;
}
```

In the cpp file I have to register a callback with the C library where I get to give it a pointer. I want to forward this function call to the corresponding member function. The client (i.e. the user of this function) doesn't have to know about this detail at all:

```
static void from_c_func(void *ptr_to_class_impl) {
    static_cast<some_class::impl *>(ptr_to_class_impl)->from_c_func();
}

void some_class::some_init() {
    create_c_thing(static_cast<void *>(this->m_pimpl.get()), from_c_func);
}
```

The problem is that `some_class::impl` is declared private. I can only think of imperfect solutions:

1. Make the `class impl;` public in the header file. This is not ideal because it really should be `private` - it just happens to be an implementation detail that a non-class function needs to see it.
2. Put `from_c_func` in the header file and `friend` it. This is not ideal because the implementation details of `some_class` are leaking out. Changing the implementation may require changing the header file, which would then recompile a lot of things which don't need recompilation, which would make me unhappy.
3. Give `from_c_func` a pointer to `some_class` itself, and then call a function on `some_class`. This would require putting that function in the header file, which is again, an implementation detail - and it would have to be `public` anyway for the non-friend function to call it.

What to do? My best bet so far seems to be #1, but is there any better way?

Comment: Normally, the whole thing go in `impl`. so `some_class::fun` just forwards to `m_pimpl->fun`.

Comment: It's a bit late here, but wouldn't it help to make the shown `static void from_c_func(..)` a static member function of `impl`?

Comment: You could make `from_c_func` static in `some_class`, too, which would give it access to `impl` as well.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: true but then it'll have to be in the header file, which I don't want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may move your function in `impl`

```
static void some_class::impl::from_c_func(void *ptr_to_class_impl) {
    static_cast<some_class::impl *>(ptr_to_class_impl)->from_c_func();
}
```

Comment: Ahh yes of course... your comment led me to see the answer. Thanks! Something just didn't connect here.