# Opaque pointer to struct with template members

Tags: c++, templates, opaque-pointers

Suppose I'm building a linked list (the real data structure is completely different, but a linked list suffices for the question) whose nodes look like

```
template <typename T>
struct node
{
  struct node<T> *next;
  T data;
};
```

For my data structure, I have a lot of functions with return type `struct node *`, and I want the user to treat this type as opaque. In the linked list example, such a function could be for example `get_next(struct node<T> *n)` or `insert_after(struct node<T> *x, struct node<T> *y)`. Only very few functions, namely those that allocate `node`s or get/set their `data` field, need to know anything about `T`.

Is there a nicer way to "ignore `T`" and let the user interact only with something like a `typedef struct node * opaque_handle` for those functions that don't ever have to care about `T`? My gut reaction, coming from C, is just to cast to and from `void*`, but that doesn't sound very elegant.

**Edit:** CygnusX1's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38031196/opaque-pointer-to-struct-with-template-members#comment63503486_38031306) has convinced me that I'm asking for too many guarantees from the type system at the same time that I'm trying to circumvent too many of those guarantees. I will fall back to letting `T` be `void *` at the cost of casting and indirection.

Comment: maybe it doesn't sound elegant but it is widely used practice. read about [pimpl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) for example. Have a forward-declaration `struct T` in public header and use `T*` in `struct node` (doesn't need to be template in this case)

Comment: Is there a specific need to design your data structure in a way that exposes the `node<T>` type? Why not model it after the other containers in the standard (user interface functions return `T` instead of `node<T>`)?

Comment: You might want to have a look how [STL](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/) collections deal with the problem. They don't actually give end-user access to implementation structure like e.g. `node`. Their interface contains an abstract understandable for end-user types as `iterator` `value_type` `reference` and so on.

Comment: @user2296177: My point is *exactly* to avoid exposing `node<T>` (for almost all functions). I want something à la `typedef struct node<T> * handle_t` and have most functions take and return `handle_t`.

Comment: @gspr The thing is that you don't have to expose `node<T>` at all. From the POV of the user, your data structure functions return `T`'s. Memory management should be done internally by the data structure or by a base class. Like @WF suggested, just look at one of the standard containers for inspiration on interface.

Answer (score 1):

While you don't care about what `T` is, you most like want to differenciate it from a different type - say `U`, don't you?
You probably want the following to raise an error:

```
node<T>* elem1 = ...
node<U>* elem2 = ...
elem1 = elem2
```

There are a few ways to make your code simpler without sacrificing the type checking or run-time perforamce:

- If you use C++11, consider using `auto` instead of explicitly naming the type when using your functions
- If `node<T>` is very common in your code, you can set a global-scope `typedef`

Also note, that in the context of `node<T>` definition, using a plain `node` (without template arguments) is allowed.

If you really want to hide the contents of the `node`, consider implementing the [pimpl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972588/is-the-pimpl-idiom-really-used-in-practice) pattern as suggested by mvidelgauz.

Comment: To the first part of your answer: Well, for *some* functions, yes. But for a lot of the functions (such as inserting a new, already-allocated, node in the linked list example) there is absolutely no need to know anything about the fields in the struct following the first one. A lot of my functions *only* need to know that the struct starts with a pointer to a node. `T` can be a million bytes of crazy stuff for all they care.

Comment: Regarding the `typedef`: But I can't do `typedef struct node<T> * foo`, can I? If I could, almost all of my functions would take and return the `foo` type, and would work by knowing that "`foo` is a pointer to a `node<T>`, and I don't care what `T` is, for I'll only need the first field which is always a pointer to another `node<T>`".

Comment: @gspr You still need to know that the second element you insert is of the same type as the first - even if it is million bytes of crazy stuff.

Comment: Do I, if it's already allocated elsewhere (by someone with knowledge of what `T` is, of course)?

Comment: @gspr Regarding the global-level typedef - you shouldn't use it for the `node<T>` definition. However, if `node<T>` for a specific `T` is dominant in your project and has some meaning that you can name, you can definetely `typedef` it and use it as such. I would still name it `FooPtr` and not `Foo` if you name the pointer type.

Comment: @gspr You need to know that the stuff allocated by someone else matches the type contained by your list. Consider that you could have `node<T>` and `node<U>` types flying around. You still need to ensure that you don't mistakenly put a `node<U>` into a list of `T`-s. Knowledge that `T` and `U` are different is useful. You could in theory walk around it with type tagging without providing implementation, but having a plain `T` and `U` is usually simpler.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, good point. I guess I want to opt out of that specific type-safety.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use boost, then boost::any or boost::variant may be able to help implement heterogeneous containers.

Is something like this what you're after?:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/any.hpp>
#include <list>

using Collection = std::list<boost::any>;
using Node = Collection::iterator;

static Collection anys;

template<typename T>
Node insert_after(T const& obj, Node start_pos = anys.end())
{
    return anys.insert(start_pos, boost::any(obj));
}

void print_type(boost::any const& a)
{
    if (a.type() == typeid(int)) { std::cout << "int" << std::endl; }
    else if (a.type() == typeid(float)) { std::cout << "float" << std::endl; }
}

int main()
{
    const auto node1 = insert_after(int(1));
    const auto node2 = insert_after(float(2.57));
    const auto node3 = insert_after(int(3));

    std::cout << boost::any_cast<int>(*node1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << boost::any_cast<float>(*node2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << boost::any_cast<int>(*node3) << std::endl;

    print_type(*node1);
    print_type(*node2);
    print_type(*node3);

    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
1
2.57
3
int
float
int
```

Comment: He doesn't want a heterogeneous container, he simply wants to obscure the fact that his nodes are `node<T>` with some other type that has no information about `T`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but most of boost is so black-magic to me that I try to avoid using it unless absolutely neccessary :-)

Comment: @user2296177 Ah, I thought based on the other comments that OP wanted to build a list whose nodes may contain different T's, sorry.