# c++ Limiting core class visibility and providing clean interface

Tags: c++, inheritance, class-design

I have an `Engine` class that has core logic, however there is a chance this class will be replaced by a third party engine with similar functionalities, so I want minimum impact to rest of the application.

I have another class called `Adapter` that allows simple interface with the `Engine` class and also provides some value-added functionality on top of the `Engine` class.

I then have another class called `OrderProcessor` that I want to expose to rest of the application that has a much simpler interface.

I want `Engine` and `Adapter` hidden from rest of the application and `OrderProcesseor` as the only interface for rest of the application.

How do I go about designing this and which access modifier to use where? Is there a design pattern that does it?

This is what I have but I don't think it's right.

```
//This is the core functionality. Might have to replace this class with a third //party implementation
//Want to hide it as much as possible
class Engine
{
private:
    char* ip;
    char* port;

protected:
    Engine();

    bool Connect();
    bool DisConnect();
    bool SendOrder(Message msg);
    bool CancelOrder (CancelMessage cxl);
    Message ReceiveOrder();
};


//This is an interface to the engine and provides value added functions
//Don't want this known to anyone except the OrderPRocessor
class Adapter : public Engine
{
private:
    int TotalAmount;
    double DollarAmount;

protected:
    bool Start(char*ip, char* port); //this will call Engine's connect() and do other things
    bool Stop (); //this will call Engine's Disconnect
    int TotalInventory();
    double TotalSales();
    double TotalCommission();    
};


//This class is the main interface to the rest of the application for order 
//processing related functionality.
class OrderProcessor 
{
public:
    OrderProcessor();
    ~OrderProcessor();
    Stats SendStats();
    ManageInventory();

private:
    Adapter adapter;
};
```

Comment: Might be useful [Is the pImpl idiom really used in practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972588/is-the-pimpl-idiom-really-used-in-practice)

Comment: `ip` should be `const char *` at least. Port, probably, int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `Engine` and `Adapter` private *nested* classes of `OrderProcessor`:

```
class OrderProcessor 
{
public:
    OrderProcessor();
    ~OrderProcessor();

    Stats SendStats();
    ManageInventory();

private:
    class Engine
    {
        // ...
    };

    class Adapter : public Engine
    {
        // ...
    };

    Adapter adapter;
};
```

If you want to more granular access limits, make 'key tags':

```
class OrderProcessor
{
public:
    class OpenSesame
    {
        friend ClassThatCanAccessTreasure;
    private:
        OpenSezame() {}; // = default is not sufficient
    };

    int AccessTreasure(int arg1, int arg2, OpenSesame key = {});
};
```

Note that in the above scheme you don't need to pass `key`, because it's defaulted. Since the default value is instantiated in caller context, only friends of `OpenSesame` can call `AccessTreasure`. This defaulting scheme works as long as you don't have varargs/parameter pack; if you do, you need to pass it before those and pass it manually.