# Should I set class member on init (requires dynamic allocation) or assign later

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a `class A` which should hold an instance of `class B` (pointer or straight), and for some reasons `B` cannot be initiated in `A`'s MIL, but later in the constructor's body.

For what I understand I have 2 options:

1. Init `B` in MIL (with empty or partial constructor), and set up relevant fields later.
2. Hold `B*` and dynamically allocate it when I have all the information. This will require `new` though.

I guess option 1 is better performance-wise. If performance is not an issue, which should I prefer?

Comment: If you have all the information you need later in the constructor body, you could write a helper functions and remove the constructor body, calling the functions in the member initializer list

Comment: C++17 also adds `std::optional`

Comment: Option 2 could use a `std::unique_ptr`. Don't know if this works better or worse than the other suggestions offered due to the unknown circumstances of your case. Need more context to give a decent answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the pImpl idiom really used in practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972588/is-the-pimpl-idiom-really-used-in-practice)

Answer (score 1):

I would say this generally depends on whether the a is of any use if the b allocation/initialization fails. If it's useless without b make it part of the ctor and let the exception propagate if either the b allocation or initialization fails. If a can be used without b then the b initialization can be put off.