# Where is pimpl used in C++ apps/libs? any examples?

Tags: c++, qt, design-patterns, poco-libraries

pimpl idiom allows to reduce compilation dependencies in projects and have binary compatibility at the same time.

In other words you can change private implementation of a class without the need to recompile client's code.

Where can I find examples of such approach? Do you know any open source libraries or apps that uses it?

I know about QT and Poco:

- [D-Pointer - Qt Wiki](https://wiki.qt.io/D-Pointer)
- [poco/IPAddress.h at develop · pocoproject/poco](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Net/include/Poco/Net/IPAddress.h) (but is this correct to include 'impl' header file in the 'public' header file? Any change in that private impl will cause recompilation).

Comment: I've just found an older, similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972588/is-the-pimpl-idiom-really-used-in-practice

Answer (score 2):

> Where can I find examples of such approach? Do you know any open
>   source libraries or apps that uses it?

[Qt](http://wiki.qt.io/Get_the_Source). Specific module example: [QGraphicsItem.cpp](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/graphicsview/qgraphicsitem.cpp.html), filled with `d_ptr`. Private part [interface](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/graphicsview/qgraphicsitem_p.h.html). The whole [thing](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/graphicsview/) with both public and private modules.

A private implementation makes a lot of sense in case of porting the whole library/framework to a different platform. You just put a different files for implementation in while keeping the public interface as is. And the implementation is accessible via `d_ptr->`.

For the curious: non-Qt Pimpl C++ 11 [example](https://github.com/sqjk/pimpl_ptr).

Comment: yes, yes, QT heavily uses this pattern. Do you know other libraries?