# Wrap the includes of a header-only library in a single cpp file

Tags: c++

When I use a big header-only library like [Boost Spirit](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/), I often want to isolate its includes into a single cpp file (`parser.cpp`),
in order to reduce the needed compilation time to one file only. The goal is that when a source file (`main.cpp`) needs the Spirit facilities,
it can include a header file which presents a front class with *no* reference to any Spirit stuff, letting this source file compile quickly.
Only one cpp file (`parser.cpp`) needs to include the Spirit headers and take more time to compile.

But how to create a class which needs Spirit internally, without any reference to it into its declaration?
The only way I found is by using a pointer member to an incomplete wrapper class (`QiParser`), then use `new` and `delete` internally
to create the real parser.

My question is: is there a better way to do this, without using `new` and `delete`?

Here is the kind of code I use now:

## main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "parser.h"

int main (int, char **)
{
    Parser p;
    int n = 0;
    p.parse("78", n);
    std::cout << "The parsed number is " << n << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

## parser.h

```
#include <string>

class QiParser; //< Incomplete class declaration

class Parser {
public:
    Parser();
    ~Parser();
    bool parse(const std::string &s, int &result) const;
private:
    QiParser *qi_parser; //< The only way I found to not include
                         //  the Spirit headers in this file
};
```

## parser.cpp

```
#include "parser.h"
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

// The QiParser class is only present to solve my problem;
// I would like to put this code directly into the Parser class, but without showing
// any Spirit stuff inside the parser.h header file
struct QiParser : qi::grammar<std::string::const_iterator, int()>
{
    QiParser() : base_type(start)
    {
        start %= qi::int_;
    }
    qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, int()> start;
};


// Implementation of the Parser class:

Parser::Parser()
{
    qi_parser = new QiParser;
}

Parser::~Parser()
{
    delete qi_parser;
}

bool Parser::parse(const std::string &s, int &result) const
{
    auto iter = s.begin(), end = s.end();
    return qi::parse(iter, end, *qi_parser, result);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use `std::unique_ptr<QiParser> qi_parser;` instead of `QiParser * qi_parser;`. This is known as the [PImpl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972588/is-the-pimpl-idiom-really-used-in-practice) idiom