# How to get rid of header dependency?

Tags: c++, dependencies, header-files

I'm working on a software library, where one of the headers is written like this:

```
#include "exprtk.hpp"

class ExprtkWrapper {
    typedef exprtk::symbol_table<double> symbol_table_t;
    typedef exprtk::expression<double>     expression_t;
    typedef exprtk::parser<double>             parser_t;


public:

    API ExprtkWrapper( std::string expression_string );

    API ExprtkWrapper( );

    API ~ExprtkWrapper();

    API double eval(double x1 = 0.0, double x2 = 0.0, double x3 = 0.0, double x4 = 0.0);

    API double eval(std::vector<double> &p);

private:

    expression_t *expression = nullptr;

    symbol_table_t *symbol_table = nullptr;

    parser_t * parser = nullptr;    
};
```

It needs `exprtk` library to work. The problem is, that `exprtk.hpp` is a header-only library and I don't want it to be copied wherever I include my header. **Is there any elegant way to rewrite the header to get `exprtk.hpp` to the corresponding .cpp file?**

I've tried simply rewriting my class into the cpp file and leaving just declaration in the header, but then I'm getting the error:

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class ExprtkWrapper’
```

Comment: When you are willing to use something out of a header only library, you always have to include the whole file. What you can do to reduce compile time is to use pre compiled headers.

Comment: It looks like `exprtk` provides templates. You should read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).

Comment: If you aren't exposing any templates to you library's users, then you can simply not expose that header. Presumably, any template you need from that library would have been instantiated when you compile your library. You'd need some facade header that hides `exprtk` related details.

Comment: Pimpl idiom might help. Looks like you only use the library in the private part of the class - Pimpl is designed precisely to hide that.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thank you very much! Would you mind to write a short example of such facade header?

Comment: @Eenoku Take a moment to read about the [pimpl idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972588/is-the-pimpl-idiom-really-used-in-practice). It can be used to hide any implementation details used by your class.