# How wrap a C++ class into another C++ class to hide <future> and be able to compile with /clr

Tags: c++, c++-cli, clr

I intend to use a c++ lib from a dotnet core application. I am trying to create a Wrapper around this c++ lib.

The class I try to wrap is Client ( see : https://github.com/theomessin/jetbridge/blob/develop/Client/Client.hh ) :

```
#pragma once

#include <Windows.h>

#include <future>
#include <map>

#include "../Protocol/Protocol.hh"

namespace jetbridge {

class Client {
 private:
  void* simconnect = 0;
  std::map<int, std::promise<Packet*>*> requests;

 public:
  Client(void* simconnect);
  void handle_received_client_data_event(void* event);
  Packet* request(char data[], int timeout = 1000);
};

}  // namespace jetbridge
```

As you can see, it includes future

I created a C++ CLR project, added the native c++ Client lib and created simple `ClientWrapper.h` / `ClientWrapper.cpp` files :

ClientWrapper.h

```
#pragma once
#include "../Client/Client.hh"
using namespace System;

namespace ClrClient {
public
ref class ClientWrapper {};
}
```

ClientWrapper.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"

#include "ClientWrapper.h"
```

I am not able to compile this code, because `<future>` is not supported when compiling with `/clr` or `/clr:pure`

I did my research and found several discussions where it was suggested to first wrap the c++ class into another c++ class that does not expose the future.

```
Client.hh > ClientNativeWrapper.h > ClientClrWrapper.h
```

I understand this suggestion but I don't understand how to proceed to "not expose" this `#include <future>` by including `Client.hh` in another c++ class, it will still be visible when compiling the c++/cli wrapper class in the end.

Comment: I know nothing about CLR, but it seems you want the use the PImpl idiom: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972588/is-the-pimpl-idiom-really-used-in-practice.

Answer (score -1):

As you state it, `/clr` is stuck at C++17 with no current plan to move forward. `<future>` is C++20 (see this [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vs-2019-preview-2-toolset-v142-clr-and-stdclatest/435513))

There are two approaches that I can suggest, but one solution. A static or dynamic library used by your wrapper.

The problem is you need to hide the C++20 to the compiler compiling with /clr.

Thus PIMPL idiom + library is my suggestion.

The PIMPL part would be used in libA (a static library is probably the best option) but all of the `<future>` parts internal in source files.

Then a C++17 wrapper that compiles with /clr and links in the libA that contains the C++20 code. No parts of the  or C++20 may then leak out of your library through header files included by the wrapper in C++17.