# Refactoring : delegate friendship in sub-functions

Tags: c++, c++11, friend, friend-function

I refactor a code where a class has a friend function doing a lot of stuff.

```
class Foo
{
  friend void do_something(Foo& foo);
};

void do_something(Foo& foo)
{
  // More than 2000 lines of ugly code
}
```

I would like to split the content of `do_something` in several small functions. Something looking like this :

```
void do_something(Foo& foo)
{
  if(case_1) do_1(foo);
  else if(case_2) do_2(foo);
  else if(case_3) do_3(foo);
  //...
}
```

Is there a design where I can transfert the friendship to the sub-fuctions `do_x(Foo&)` without having to declare them in the class, or something similar in order to split the code ?

***Note :** C++11 only*

***Note :** I don't want to write the sub-functions as maccros*

Comment: `do_something` can access them and pass them as parameters to the subfunctions

Comment: Instead of calling e.g. `do_1(foo)`, call `do_1(foo.var1, foo.var2)`.

Comment: I'd say the question belongs there: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ rather than to SO... But on topic: what is the key factor that makes avoiding private functions worth it? Not expanding visible interface (guessing here)? I see several options here: 1. as @Someprogrammerdude has just written 2. using [PIMPL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972588/is-the-pimpl-idiom-really-used-in-practice) to name the lowest hanging fruits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of having `do_something` as function calling other sub-functions, I would suggest you to create an analogous class `DoSomehting`.

Then you could declare this class as a friend with `friend class DoSomehting;`. So these sub-functions could be its private methods. The method to call -- could be a public method named e.g. like `void DoSomehting::process(Foo& foo)`:

```cpp
class Foo
{
  friend class DoSomething;
};

class DoSomething
{
public:
    void process(Foo& foo)
    { 
        if(case_1) do_1(foo);
        else if(case_2) do_2(foo);
        else if(case_3) do_3(foo);
        //...
    }  

private:
    void do_1(Foo& foo);
    void do_2(Foo& foo);
    void do_3(Foo& foo);
};
```

Comment: Is there an advantage in doing this over the other suggestions made in the comments?  Wouldn't `DoSomething` be stateless, in which case it doesn't really add anything.

Comment: Well, I think my answer solves the problem that you do not have to declare all the functions friends. Only one class.

Comment: The solutions suggested in the comments don't propose declaring all the sub-functions as friends.

Comment: My solution is also a solution. The person who asked the question, can just choose a preferable one, I think.

Comment: @PaulSanders the solution suggested in the comments is not easily scalable, for example, it `Foo` has private types or private member functions `do_something` needs, it would be a pain to transfer them to `do_1`.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Yes, I see it now, sorry Jenya.