# Pointer losing visibility during cross-class access

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, pointers

I have an issue where class **GUI_System** accesses a member of class **ThreadManger** through class **GUI_Top**. What happens is that accessing the member from its original container shows its correct contents, but when accessed from **GUI_System** it doesn't.

I have found out that in class **ThreadManger**, prior to the member in question, there are some other objects that if i comment them out, the behavior is changed.

1. if i leave everything in, then **StructLoadSystem** has an address of 0x0
   [image]
2. if i comment out one of the two method pointers then the address of **StructLoadSystem** is not 0x0 anymore, but is still different from that seen from **ThreadManger**.
   [image]
3. if i further comment out some more objects, then the address returns to be 0x0.
   [image]

My issue happens on a big project of mine with a lot of interdependent files so i have stripped to the bare minimum the code in order to create a test-case. Please also note that i have to keep the files separate, because for some reason if i put everything in the same file, the issue disappears so including order might be a thing to look into.

For convenience i have created a Visual Studio solution that can be launched directly.
You can find it [here](https://github.com/NeuralDip/TestCase1.git).

Can someone give any ideas of what could be happening and/or what i could do to further debug this?

Comment: You need to produce one file with the minimum code needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Unfortunately as i say in the question, the issue disappears if i put everything in one file. Which does not solve my issue.

Comment: It sounds like the commenting out you mentioned in your post is just shifting the symptom and may not be related to the actual cause. Someone recently mentioned [Address Sanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer) and while I haven't (yet) used it myself, it sounds like it might be worthwhile trying for your problem.

Comment: @avi I agree it's excellent, but no such thing in MSVC, unfortunately.

Comment: @PaulSanders • [VS Address Sanitizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/sanitizers/asan?view=msvc-170)

Comment: @Eljay Interesting, thank you.  I shall see what it has to say about my own code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded your project and had a look at it. The primary issue seems to be that you are storing a pointer to a method on a forward-declared type. The size and/or padding for such values is unknown without the definition of what it points to.

Here is your `ThreadManger` [sic] stripped back:

```
class GUI_System;

class ThreadManger
{
    class JobsClass
    {
    public:
        void (GUI_System::* EndEvent)();
    };

public:
    JobsClass MyJobs;                      //<-- Unknown size, if GUI_System is not defined
    ServiceStruct* StructQuitApplication;  //<-- Offset might change depending on above
};
```

And so, in `ThreadManger.cpp` you have this situation:

```
//<-- At this point, GUI_System is NOT defined
#include "ThreadManger.h"
```

Whereas in `GUI_System.cpp` you have this:

```
#include "GUI_System.h"
//<-- At this point, GUI_System IS defined
#include "GUI_Top.h"     //<-- This includes ThreadManger.h
```

When I compile the project as 32-bit, the following occurs:

- `ThreadManger` thinks that `sizeof(ThreadManger::MyJobs)` is 16
- `GUI_System` thinks that `sizeof(ThreadManger::MyJobs)` is 4

When I compile the project as 64-bit, the following occurs:

- `ThreadManger` thinks that `sizeof(ThreadManger::MyJobs)` is 24
- `GUI_System` thinks that `sizeof(ThreadManger::MyJobs)` is 8

That means the offset of `ThreadManger::StructQuitApplication` is different in these two translation units and in fact the issue is caused by your `ThreadManger` implementation, not `GUI_System`. It's a nasty one for sure, being sensitive to the order of header inclusion.

The quick fix is to `#include "GUI_System.h"` in `ThreadManger.h`, instead of forward-declaring it.

That's not to say this is a "good" fix, because more fundamentally your design is much too interconnected. The tight coupling of these classes all knowing about each-other's members is something that should be avoided. And nothing quite illustrates that better than the issue you've just encountered. I highly recommend you rethink your design.

At the very least, you ought to be making a lot of this stuff private and expose functionality via methods. As for the `JobsClass` stuff, you can use the [PIMPL idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972588) by forward-declaring it and storing privately as a pointer. Then, in the implementation you would ensure you have included `GUI_System.h` so that the class can be properly defined.

You may also consider using `std::function` and lambdas instead of pointer-to-method for your jobs. Alternatively, define an abstract `Job` class with a `Execute` method, which is called when dispatching an event. Whichever way you do it, ideally a "thread manager" should be general purpose and not need to know anything about who or what is using it.

Comment: You are a legend!! thank you very much for taking the time and giving the explanation.