# How should one overload functions with const/non-const parameters?

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading

I have the following code:

```
// string specializations
void foo(const char *a, const char *b);
void foo(const char *a, const std::string &b);
void foo(const std::string &a, const char *b);
void foo(const std::string &a, const std::string &b);

// generic implementation
template<typename TA, typename TB>
void foo(TA a, TA b)
{...}
```

The problem is that this test case:

```
char test[] = "test";
foo("test", test);
```

ends up calling the templated version of `foo`. Obviously, I can just add a few more overloads with various mixes of non-`const` parameters, but I want to know: is there's a better way to overload `foo` such that it is specialized on all `const` and non-`const` pairings of strings? One that doesn't require me to hope I haven't missed some permutation of argument types?

Comment: `char *test = "test"` isn't something you should do. `"test"` _is_ `const char*`.

Comment: SFINAE for types that aren't convertible to `std::string`, or simply make `std::string` and require callers to convert

Comment: Because you _also_ missed that `"test"` is of type `const char[5]`, not `const char*`.

Comment: @jogojapan, Technically, `"test"` is `const char[5]`.

Comment: Sorry, yes. My point, of course, was the `const` (and conversion to `const char*` isn't a problem, while conversion to `char *` is borderline and only possible because of a deprecated exception in the rules for type casting).

Comment: Actually, my apologies. It shouldn't have been `char *test = "test";`, it's `char test[] = "test";`

Comment: I ran in to a similar problem when trying to use ``Perfect Forwarding`` and template specialization for the ``foo_set()`` method in a different question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240015/c11-reentrant-class-locking-strategy  Maybe you can glean something from there that's of use. If I had a better answer/suggestion, I'd post the improvement as an actual answer instead of a half-comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Mooing Duck's suggestion, this is my solution:

```
// string specialization
void foo(const std::string &a, const std::string &b);

template<typename TA, typename TB>
typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_constructible<std::string, TA>::value &&
    std::is_constructible<std::string, TB>::value
>::type foo(TA a, TB b)
{
    foo(std::string(std::move(a)), std::string(std::move(b)));
}

// generic implementation
template<typename TA, typename TB>
typename std::enable_if<
    !std::is_constructible<std::string, TA>::value ||
    !std::is_constructible<std::string, TB>::value
>::type foo(TA a, TB b)
{...}
```

Comment: You can `std::forward` only [Universal References](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers).

Comment: I would prefer `std::is_convertible` over `std::is_constructible` since it also catches conversions not realized by `std::string`'s constructors (like user-defined implicit conversion operators).

Comment: It's not incorrect to use `std::forward` like you do here, but in this instance it may be more straightforward to use `std::move` directly, since that's what it boils down to.

Comment: @ChristianRau `std::is_constructible` will properly deal with conversion operators. The difference between `std::is_constructible<T, Arg>::value` and `std::is_convertible<Arg, T>::value` (mind the order of parameters) is the difference between `T t(std::declval<Arg>());` and `T t = std::declval<Arg>();`.

Comment: @LucDanton Ah, thanks for the clarification (when thinking about it, it makes sense that `std::is_constructible` catches conversion operators, too). In fact it seems `std::is_constructible` catches even more, since `std::is_convertible` wouldn't catch explicit constructors. Not sure if this is good or bad here, but I guess it's irrelevant in this case, since calling `foo(std::string::allocator_type(), ...)` is probably pretty unlikely anyway.

Comment: @LucDanton (and Mateusz Pusz): Thanks. I'm still working out the right usage. I think I need to re-watch Scott Meyers's video again. It was clear for about a week, but I don't write C++ in my day job anymore so it faded without practice.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your goals properly you could do this

```
template<typename T1,typename T2 >
void foo(T1, T2)
{
     static_assert(sizeof(T1) == 0,"Did not overload all foo's");
}

template<>
void foo<const char *a, const char *b>()
{
    ... Handle this case
}

... ect ect ect
```

This has the advantage of you handling every instance you want explicitly while generating a compilation error if you missed one.

Comment: Thanks, but I was just typing up my own answer using SFINAE and strings (thanks to Mooing Duck).

Comment: Is this really a solution? You'd still need to code many different specializations.