# data hiding in C++

Tags: c++, c, incomplete-type, data-hiding

I have some code in C, that uses incomplete structs this way ( simplified example ):

*something.h*

```
struct something;

struct something *new_something();
int work_a(struct something *something);
int work_b(struct something *something, const char *str);
void free_something(struct something *something);
```

*somecode.c*

```
int some_function()
{
    struct something *something;
    int x;

    something = new_something();
    x = work_a(something);
    free_something(something);
    return x;
}
```

I was thinking, I'm basically doing C++ here, why not try write it in C++ .
The question is ( I'm new to C++ ), how do I achieve the same in C++ ? If I try to add declare a member function of an incomplete class, I get

```
error: incomplete type 'something' named in nested name specifier
```

from clang. By writing the complete class in the header, this would lose the whole point of data hiding, and changing private vars in the class would force every file including "something.h" to recompile, which I think is not needed here. I don't need the files using "something.h" to know the size of this struct / class, I'm usually fine with having just a pointer. I suspected it should look like this:

```
 class Something;

 Something::Something();
 Something::~Something();
 int Something::work_a(int x);
```

this way I could write the same thing I did in C, only shorter, and even cleaner. Any C++ coder out there wishing to enlighten this mortal C coder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this article: [Hiding Implementation Details in C++](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42466/Hiding-Implementation-Details-in-C).  It should get you pointed in the direction you are looking.  Note that inheritance is being used to accomplish the goal.  Also understand that in C++, a struct is a class with all members having public access (includes functions, constructors, and destructors).  At a minimum, the interface has to be declared a class, then inherit from that publicly in the now hidden class implementation inside the cpp file (not another header file).

On the Pimpl design pattern, check out this Stack Overflow article: [pimpl idiom vs. bridge design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346163/pimpl-idiom-vs-bridge-design-pattern/2346202).  It should also help.

Comment: Thanks, this idea of casting the class to another class all the time in the implementation seems like a great idea, and I'm sure it is easy for the compilers to optimize it.
Only thing is, I was looking for solution in C++ that is even cleaner, less hackish than the what I wrote in C. So I'll just keep the question open. 
( BTW that pimpl thing seems horrible, I already hide things behind a pointer, I wouldn't put another pointer behind that pointer. )

Comment: @BuellaGábor Well you could always take advantage of the `dynamic_cast` operator.  It all depends on what the goal is.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is through the Pimpl design pattern where you have a pointer to some private struct/class that only your implementation knows about. Your private functions use the pointer and in theory it can be mostly inlined.

Answer (score 0):

When you allocate memory with new statement the compiler has to know how much data space to allocate. The data size of Something has be seen by the compiler before you can use new to create a Something instance.

Use something like this in Something.h

```
class Something {
public:
 Something();

private:
 struct HiddenData;
 HiddenData* m_pHidden;
};
```

Use something like this in Something.cpp

```
struct Something::HiddenData {
int a;
int b;
```

};

```
Something::Something() : m_pHidden(new HiddenData()) {
 m_pHidden->a = 1;
}
```

Comment: Wait, what? Why does the new statement need to know the size? All I ask for is a pointer, the implementation giving me that pointer, and allocating stuff would be in another compilation unit ( at least that is what I do in C ). I would understand it, if would be just a variable on the stack, but this would be just a pointer on the stack. What am I missing there?

Comment: OK, I took a quick look in Wikipedia, and it says " new is a language construct that dynamically allocates memory from free store and initialises the memory using the constructor."
So new first allocates the space itself, and calls the constructor after that. So it is not the constructor allocating it all, it just supposed to initialize already allocated data.

Comment: the error you showed: error: incomplete type 'something' named in nested name specifier is related to the compiler not having enough information about what to allocate to call the constructor and build the object. The code I showed is a good way to do the data hiding you're talking about

Comment: @BuellaGábor In pimpl you have to keep one and only one pointer. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/508ffbbc3d1b396e
GaryAsh You might want to edit your answer.

Comment: Well, as I see it, it doesn't hide the data, I have to type it there in the header. In my original version, I have only a pointer to arbitrary data, I don't want less data-hiding than that. Having a pointer to a class containing another pointer that points to the data makes it worse in my eyes, not better. It has one more indirection, and seems more hackish. As I see it now, can't use the new keyword, and still hide the data it points to, since it needs to know the size of the data.

Comment: @BuellaGábor Well, working on a pointer in C++ is a bad design. Like in case of throwing an unexpected error, your might forget to catch and call the destructor.

Comment: @GaryAsh In that code example you have one pointer typed, in a sense, yes. At the same time, I still don't believe in magic, that is work_a, in another compilation unit would somehow know about the Something on the stack of main. I suppose it needs to get the address of the instance it works on, and on that address it would find the address of the Something_private instance, and would work with that.

Comment: @Arpegius Does C++ automatically call destructors for objects on the stack when it longjumps, I mean throws an exception?
I think I really don't know enough about C++ to work in it yet...

Comment: @BuellaGábor You are right, and only solution to this to inline work_a and call private work_a like in a old C, thats a shame.
Yes it does: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02404e177d8784b8 
IMHO writing pimpl is a bit frustrating and not DRY.