# Expose only one interface from a cpp file

Tags: c++

```
//funcs.h
class A
{
   void func1();
   void func2();
};

//funcs.cpp
#include "header1.h"
#include "header2.h"
#include "func.h"
A::func1()
{
}

A::func2()
{
}

//usage.cpp
#include "header1.h"
#include "header2.h"
#include "func.h"

int main()
{
    func1();
}
```

usage.cpp is only ever going to call `func1()` and does not need to know about other functions in `funcs.h`. In order to call `func1()` from `usage.cpp`, i need to include `funcs.h` and the dependent headers like `header1.h` and `header2.h` in `usage.cpp`. Is there a way i don't have to include all these headers in `usage.cpp` because in fact it only should know about `func1`?

I don't have control over `header1.h` and `header2.h` and if there are no guards present there i get multiple definitions error.

EDIT:
if `header1.h` has some `struct` definitions it will be defined in both `usage.cpp` and `funcs.cpp` which would throw error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [data hiding in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22494309/data-hiding-in-c)

Comment: What is the question? One question. What do you mean by _interface_? There are include guards if that is what you are after.

Comment: Create new headers that do have include guards, have the new headers include the old headers. Never use the old headers again.

Comment: Do you mean you only want to declare half the class member functions in the header? Because you can't define half a class in a header file.

Comment: if `header1.h` has some struct definitions it will be defined in both `usage.cpp` and `funcs.cpp` which would throw error.

Comment: `int main() { func1(); }` vill not compile, you need to either create an instance of A or declare func1 static

Comment: @user3819404 Multiple struct definitions should not be an error.