# How to hide private base class members and methods from users

Tags: c++

Maybe I didn't make my question clear, the following answers are not answering my question. Let me make the question more specific. My question is that I have a base class to send to clients so that clients can develop derived classes at their ends. How can I hide the private methods and members?

For example, in the following code snippets, the base.h file declares the base class which provides three private virtual methods for clients to override in the derived classes. The clients can override none, any, or all of them. Assuming a client developed a derived class called "Derived", and passed the "Derived" class creator to me so that I can create the Derived class somewhere, e.g. Base* p_base = new Derived() and call p_base->Execute() to actually call client implementations of virtual functions DoInitialize(), DoExecute(), DoCleanUp().

BTW: I don't think opaque pointers will work.

In Base.h file:

```
  class Base {
        public:
              Base(); 
             ~Base();
        void Execute(); 
    
        private:
        // virtual functions to be overridden by derived classes.
        virtual void DoInitialize() {}
        virtual void DoExecute() {}
        virtual void DoCleanUp() {}
    
        private: 
        // private members and functions that are intended to hide from clients
        std::vector<float> data_; 
        ....
}
```

In Base.cpp file

```
Base::Execute() {
    DoInitialize();
    DoExecute();
    DoCleanUp();
}
```

In clients end

```
class Derived : public Base {
     public:
         Derived();
         ~Derived();

     private:
         // overide base class methods 
         void DoInitialize() {}
         void DoExecute() {}
         void DoCleanUp() {}
}
```

In my end somewhere:

```
void main() {
     Base* p = DerivedCreater(); // creater a Derived class, assumes DerivedCreater() has passed in by clients. 
     p->Execute(); // I want to call the client implementation of DoInitialize(), DoExecute(), and DoCleanUp()
}
```

Comment: Have a look here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl

Comment: `private` `virtual` functions work completely well in C++, as you already have in your example. I'm not sure I understand what the problem is here

Comment: @Human-Compiler, I think he wants to hide not just the implementation details, but also the abstracted details; aka, function names and variable names and the values the functions take and so on

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 Why making these `virtual` then? That doesn't make sense if inherited classes shouldn't provide their implementation.

Comment: Only @Human-Compiler understands my question correctly. Maybe I did not make the question clear. What I am asking is that I have a base class to send to clients so that the clients can develop the derived classes at their end. However, I don't want to expose private members and methods. How can I do that?

Comment: @Charlie then don't send them this class.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22494309/data-hiding-in-c/22494571#22494571

Comment: Also check out https://herbsutter.com/gotw/_100/

Answer (score 2):

The way to go is to have an opaque pointer to the implementation.

```
class BaseImpl;

class Base {
public:
  Base(); 
 ~Base();

private:
// virtual functions to be overridden by derived classes.
virtual void Initialize() {}

private: 

// private members and functions that are not intended to override by derived classes
void Configure() { m_impl->Configure(); }
BaseImpl* m_impl;
}
```

Then, in the `BaseImpl`, you keep a pointer to the `Base` and you call the virtual functions as wanted. You keep `BaseImpl.h` in your private includes and you don't distribute it to the library users.

See:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl

Comment: I'd make it `std::unique_ptr<BaseImpl> m_impl;` - but yes, the [pimpl idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) seems like a feasible approach.