# Hide private class members and methods from clients

Tags: c++, private

Let me make the question more specific. My question is that I have a base class to send to clients so that clients can develop derived classes at their ends. How can I hide the private methods and members?

For example, in the following code snippets, the base.h file declares the base class which provides three private virtual methods for clients to override in the derived classes. The clients can override none, any, or all of them. Assuming a client developed a derived class called "Derived", and passed the "Derived" class creator to me so that I can create the Derived class somewhere, e.g. Base* p_base = new Derived() and call p_base->Execute() to actually call client implementations of virtual functions DoInitialize(), DoExecute(), DoCleanUp().

BTW: I don't think opaque pointers will work.

In Base.h file:

```
  class Base {
        public:
              Base(); 
             ~Base();
        void Execute(); 
    
        private:
        // virtual functions to be overridden by derived classes.
        virtual void DoInitialize() {}
        virtual void DoExecute() {}
        virtual void DoCleanUp() {}
    
        private: 
        // private members and functions that are intended to hide from clients
        std::vector<float> data_; 
        ....
}
```

In Base.cpp file

```
Base::Execute() {
    DoInitialize();
    DoExecute();
    DoCleanUp();
}
```

In clients end

```
class Derived : public Base {
     public:
         Derived();
         ~Derived();

     private:
         // overide base class methods 
         void DoInitialize() {}
         void DoExecute() {}
         void DoCleanUp() {}
}
```

In my end somewhere:

```
void main() {
     Base* p = DerivedCreater(); // creater a Derived class, assumes DerivedCreater() has passed in by clients. 
     p->Execute(); // I want to call the client implementation of DoInitialize(), DoExecute(), and DoCleanUp()
}
```

Comment: I believe PIMPL is the best option. I did not repost the link because it was the first link in the other question on the same topic.

Comment: Opaque `m_impl` pointer to implementation, where `m_impl` knows `Base` and makes call to its virtual functions.

Comment: ***I have to restate my question and repost because the answers in my previous post are completely messed up.*** Usually that means one of the 2 questions will be closed as a duplicate of the other.

Comment: You may be interested in this: [_Template Method Design Pattern_](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method).

Comment: Previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64142832/how-to-hide-private-base-class-members-and-methods-from-users

Comment: To be fair, the duplicate doesn't have a good answer

Comment: There may be a better one for both of them to be duplicates of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22494309/data-hiding-in-c/22494571#22494571

Comment: Can you add a little usage example? What will the client code be able to do inside `DoInitialize()`, `DoExecute()` and `DoCleanUp()` when everything is `private`?

Comment: @Jeffrey I think your answer to the previous question was useful though :)

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo, the wider scope is that we will provide data input for DoExecute() under the hood, the user will implement DoExecute() whatever they want to process the data. The DoInitialize() and DoCleanUp() are actually executed outside of Base::Execute() , but here I just want to simply the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should have an interface class. It has no data members, only pure virtual functions. The clients can write whatever class using the interface class as a base and implement the virtual functions. They have to construct the object and pass you an interface pointer. Then you can call those virtual functions without knowing how they are implemented.

If you want the client object to carry a pointer for you, make that part of the interface functions (get, set), don’t add it to the interface class as a data member.

See an example interface here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3c26e8cc0bb4dc4

Comment: This seems to be the opposite of what OP wants. _pimpl_ seems more like what OP needs.

Comment: Pimpl is for when you want to isolate your concrete class implementation so other code is not affected by changes in the hidden impl struct or class. Here, the 3 virtual functions are the interface.

Comment: Yes, they are the interface to the hidden data somehow - The reason for using _pimpl_  may be that you want to isolate it like you say, but it may also be because you'd like to actually hide all the implementation details from the end users, which is what I personally think OP wants. However, I think it's a bit unclear _how_ it's going to use it since it doesn't have access to _any_ base class member functions in the example code.

Comment: @Khouri Giordano, thank you for your answer. It seems like what I am looking for, but I am not sure if I get exactly what you mean. Do you mind to write a simple sample code based on the sample codes in the question? I very appreciate it.

Comment: @Charlie If you create something that could pass for a pure interface, there will be no hidden `std::vector<float> data_; ` in your base class.

Comment: The client uses the interface class as a base and only talks to you via the create function that returns an interface pointer and the interface’s setter, getters, methods and other functions. The interface should either have a public virtual destructor (can’t return anything Or throw) OR a virtual Destroy() (can return something or throw) and private non-virtual destructor.