# hiding inner class implementation using namespace

Tags: c++, api, namespaces

I am developing  a library and a would like to provide my users a public interface separate from the real implementation that is hidden in a namespace. This way, I could change only the class HiddenQueue without changing myQueue that will be exposed to users only.

If I put the C++ code of HiddenQueue in the myQueue.cpp file the compiler complains saying _innerQueue has incomplete type. I thought that the linker was able to resolve this. What I am doing wrong here?

```
// myQueue.h
namespace inner{
    class HiddenQueue;
};

class myQueue{

public:
    myQueue();
);

private:

    inner::HiddenQueue _innerQueue;

};

///////////////////////////

// myQueue.cpp
namespace inner{
    class HiddenQueue{};
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler needs to know the exact memory layout of an object by looking at the header file it's defined in.

Your code says that class `MyQueue` has a member of type `InnerQueue`, which will be part of the memory layout of `MyQueue` objects. Therefore, to deduce the memory layout of `MyQueue` it needs to know the memory layout of `InnerQueue`. Which it does not, because you say "oh well, it's defined elsewhere".

What you are trying to do is closely related to "the [PIMPL](http://aszt.inf.elte.hu/~gsd/halado_cpp/ch09s03.html) [idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60570/why-should-the-pimpl-idiom-be-used)"/"compiler firewall" technique.

To solve the problem, you must either include HiddenQueue.h in your header or declare _innerqueue as a pointer:

```
class myQueue {

public:
    myQueue();

private:

    inner::HiddenQueue* _pinnerQueue;
};
```

Using a pointer is possible because a pointer has a known memory size (dependent on your target architecture), therefore the compiler doesn't need to see the full declaration of `HiddenQueue`.

Comment: +1 For PIMPL. Here's an article from the guy who coined the term: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/024.htm

Comment: Well, in the bottom line PIMPL incurs some runtime speed cost and offers you gains on ease of maintenance and compilation speed. Admittedly the runtime speed cost is a non-issue in the general case (and when it isn't, you probably know it's important), but IMHO there's no need for PIMPL in codebases less than a certain size.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to make a member of a class, you need to have a definition for it and not only a declaration.  (A declaration is enough for a pointer or a reference to the class).

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide pointer to _innetQueue rather then the object itself:

```
std::auto_ptr<inner::HiddenQueue> _innerQueue;
```

Search form pimpl ideom or d-pointer

Comment: Don't use `auto_ptr` for the Pimpl idiom, its weird copy/assignment semantics are more trouble that they're worth. `unique_ptr` or `scoped_ptr` are much better, and you can just code a very simple class if necessary.

Comment: `unique_ptr` comes only with C++0x, `scoped_ptr` require boost. `auto_ptr` exists anywhere. Also when your class is not copyable it is more then fine to use `auto_ptr` -- in other words: you need smart pointer and standard C++ provides only `auto_ptr`