# Right way to instantiate instance-variables in C++

Tags: c++, stack, instantiation, instance-variables

I want to ask where in C++ is the right place to instantiate a instance-variables? I think it should not be in the class declaration, but otherwise I don`t see any disadvantages apart from poor object-oriented design:

`class A{ member m; };`

I think it should better be like:

`class A{ extern member m; };`

But I don`t know how to realize it without a pointer like this:

`class A{ member* m };`

`A::A(){ m = new member; }`

Is there a "clean solution" to realize this on the stack (without using pointers)?

Comment: Why wouldn't you do it in the class?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Could you please clarify the question? A field within an object is "instantiated" together with the object itself. Did you actually mean "class-level" or "static" member?

Comment: I meant "class level" but my problem was that I thought an instance-variable is defined within the class declaration - sorry, my fault...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the constructor initialization list to construct all your member variables as you need.

```
A::A(const member& memberArg)
     : m(memberArg) 
{ }
```

Look at [this](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html) for more info.

Comment: you mean `class A{ member m; };` and then `member m;`...`A::A():m(m){}`

Comment: Better make the parameter `const member &`.

Comment: yes, that is what I mean. An instance variable in C++ is exactly that: `class A{ member m; };`

Comment: Ok thanks, but what if I don`t have a member object for constructor initialization list from higher level - is there a chance to do this within class A (without new/pointer)?

Comment: You mean: if your member is, e.g, a `long`? The construction init. list will work equally. In any case, you can also assign in the constructor body: `A::A(const long memberArg) { m = memberArg; }`

Answer (score 4):

I think you have a misunderstanding of how objects are instantiated. If all you do is declare a class, no member variables are actually instantiated. It isn't until you construct an instance of that class that its member variables exist.

Here's an example to show when a member object gets instantiated:

```
class ClassA
{
public:
  ClassA() { std::cout << "Hello!\n"; }
};

class ClassB
{
public:
  ClassA objA;
};

int main()
{
  // do some work
  ClassB objB; // here, a ClassB object is created, and with it its member ClassA object, so "Hello!" is printed
  return 0;
}
```

As to exactly how you specify what kind of ClassA object to create if its constructor requires arguments, the other answers do a fine job explaining it.

Comment: Thank you Sean, you are right, I had a misunderstanding of how objects in C++ are instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

> I think it should not be in the class declaration, but otherwise I don`t see any disadvantages apart from poor object-oriented design:
>
> `class A{ member m; };`

What in your mind makes this poor OO design? This is the preferred mechanism in C++.

> I think it should better be like:
>
> `class A{ extern member m; };`

This isn't valid code. Qualifying member data with a storage class specification such as `extern` is illegal.

> But I don`t know how to realize it without a pointer like this:
>
> `class A{ member* m; };`
> `A::A(){ m = new member; }`

That will work, but why do that? It looks to me like you are trying to import a Java POV into C++. Everything is allocated, and everything is a reference in Java. In many (most!) cases there is no reason to allocate data members in C++. All it does is add an unneeded indirection and add a place where memory can leak.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use member initializers: they are the only way to initialize class members that have a constructor that requires parameters, and the cleanest way to initialize other class members.

If you have class A and a member m with a constructor:

```
class A { member m; }
```

You want

```
class A { member m; A(); }

A::A()
: m(<constructor params>)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would declare your instance variables in your `.h` file:

**A.h**

```
class A {

   public:
      A();
   private:
      int value;
      double someOtherValue;
}
```

You can instantiate them in your .cpp file like so:

**A.cpp**

```
A::A(): value(5), someOtherValue(10.0)
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the member object is to be totally controlled by the enclosing `A` object, your first example is the proper way to do it. It does have the downside of requiring a complete definition of `member` at the point where `A` is defined.

You could check out the [pimpl idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60570/why-should-the-pimpl-idiom-be-used) to reduce coupling, but that still requires the object to be heap-based and not stack-based.