# Is there a way to share 'struct' among source files while not exposing it in a header file?

Tags: c, struct, typedef, private

Lets say I have a header file **foo.h** which declares a struct variable

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct foo_struct foo_s;

foo_s foo_function(int a);
foo_s bar_function(int b);
```

and a source file **foo.c** which actually defines the structure

```
#include "foo.h"

struct foo_struct
{
   int a;
   int b;
};

foo_s foo_function(int a)
{
    foo_s fs;
    fs.a = a;
    return fs;
}
```

Now I want to access the structure defined in **foo.c** in another source file **bar.c** so I try the following:

```
#include "foo.h"

foo_s bar_function(int b)

{
  foo_s fb;
  fb.b = b;

  return fb;
}
```

...and fail with *bar.c:3:7: error: return type is an incomplete type*

I sort of understand what the problem is but is there a workaround?

Comment: If you don't wanna expose the struct's actual type: make a private header file.

Comment: Might you be interested in the [Pimpl Idiom](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60570/10077)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're breaking your abstraction by needing to know the definition of `struct foo_struct` outside of foo.c.  The whole *point* of making a struct definition "private" to a particular source file is so that other source files aren't aware of and cannot manipulate the members of `struct foo_struct` directly.

You either need to move `bar` into foo.c, *or* you need to put the struct definition in `foo.h` (making it public), *or* you need to define an interface that allows other translation units to allocate, set, read, and deallocate items of type `foo_s` without exposing the details of its type, similar to how the routines in `stdio.h` manipulate objects of type `FILE`, something like

```
foo_s *create_foo(int a, int b);
void set_foo(foo_s *f, char *property, int value);
int get_foo(foo_s *f, char *property);
void destroy_foo(foo_s **f);  // sets f to NULL after deallocation.
```

You would add the above interface to foo.h and implement it in foo.c; functions in other translation units (source files) would use it like:

```
void blah(void)
{
  foo_s *f = create_foo(0,0);
  if (f)
  {
    set_foo(f, "a", 1);
    set_foo(f, "b", 2);

    printf("a = %d, b = %d\n", get_foo(f, "a"), get_foo(f, "b");
    destroy_foo(&f);
    assert(f == NULL);
  }
}
```

There are probably a hundred better ways to do that, but you should get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no easy workaround.

In this code

```
typedef struct foo_struct foo_s; 

foo_s fb;
fb.b = b;
```

the compiler only knows that `foo_s` is a struct, but it doesn't know if `b` is a member of that struct, or how large the struct is. And it definitely cannot know that it is the second member you want to assign a value to, so it just doesn't work.

The compiler can only tell what the code is supposed to do if you include the definition of the struct.