# Is defining classes in headers a good practice?

Tags: c++

I have read that defining functions in headers is a bad practice, but how about classes? is defining them in the header files fine?

Comment: If you want users of your library to be able to make use of those classes, where else would you define them?

Comment: This is a duplicate of dozens of existing questions.

Comment: @jogojapan, I guess you could argue that PIMPL sort of like defining the class elsewhere :p

Comment: @chris PIMPL only affects public .h vs private .h typically yes? You would still define the class in a .h that is not exposed to client

Comment: @KarthikT, I was under the impression that the implementation went in the cpp. I've not used PIMPL myself, though.

Comment: What does "defining a class" mean? I can *declare* a class (including its ctors, dtors, member functions, and member variables) and *define* a class' methods/functions by giving the executable code that runs when each function is called. Does the former or the later count as "defining the class"?

Comment: @chris Hmmm.. I am not sure what it would mean to put an _entire_ class under the pimpl idiom. There would always have to be some public-facing class left that would need to go into the header, no?

Comment: @Code-Guru The _former_ is what I'd call a class definition.

Comment: @chris Ah, yes that would work too.. Even I have no first hand experience, so cant comment beyond that.

Comment: @Code-Guru you are confusing defining a class with defining a class's methods.

Comment: @jogojapan Then my answer is "yes".

Comment: @jogojapan, Personally, I can't find an excuse to use it for compilation times, especially with the future modules that will become available. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60570/why-should-the-pimpl-idiom-be-used) seems like how one would typically implement the implementation to be private whilst defining the implementation completely in the cpp.

Comment: @jogojapan As my initial comment hints, I dislike the word "define" (or any of its cognates) in this context. "implementation" and "interface" are much more precise, IMO.

Comment: @chris Right.. the definition of `Cat` is still in the header, right? (Not the definition of all its functions, though.)

Comment: @Code-Guru I believe it's the C++ Standard that uses the word definition for this.

Comment: @jogojapan Sounds like I need to delve into the C++ standard when I have some spare time...and feel like getting back into C++ programming.

Comment: @jogojapan, That's why I said sort of in my first comment. You're still defining a class in your header, but it's not the *real* class.

Comment: @OP Perhaps you could clarify if pimpl as described by chris is what you are interested in. That would certainly be a reasonable question (although it may be a duplicate of the one chris linked).

Answer (score 1):

Unless this class is a pure template class or other class which is supposed to be inline, you'd better put class implementation into cpp files instead of header files. In a word, put interface in header files, while put implementations in cpp files.

P.S.

As @jogojapan said, I'm talking about the class implementation instead of class definition. That's because despite that OP is talking about class definition, I strongly doubt that he's actually meaning class implementation.

Comment: You are talking about the _functions_ of the class, not the class definition itself.

Comment: Yes, I realized that. But I doubt although OP is talking about class definition, he actually means class implementation.

Comment: +1 for avoiding the word "define". The words "interface" and "implementation" seem more appropriate in this context.