# Avoiding the windows header

Tags: c++, windows, directx

I'm using both win32 and directx when making a game engine + game. Win32 directly needs the window header and directx header includes it aswell.

It is a decently-sized project and I'd rather avoid exposing the windows header to the rest of the project(s) if possible. Is there any good way to bypass this issue?

Comment: I don't understand. What's the problem?

Comment: Are you saying you want to avoid `#include <windows.h>` in most project files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's only one practical way to avoid exposing a header that your implementation code needs, and that's to include the header only in the implementation.

That's called the **compiler firewall** idiom.

Often (but this is not always required) one exposes a class with a member pointer to an object of declared but incomplete type, that is defined only in the implementation file. This is usually called the [**PIMPL**](http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_100/), short for *pointer to implementation*, idiom, but it has also been called [the **handle-body** idiom and the **Cheshire Cat** idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60579/464581).

---

One alternative to a PIMPL pointer is to declare a **factory function** in the header file, where that factory function produces objects of some known type `Base`, and in the implementation file let it produce an object of a derived type `Derived` that contains the dependencies on the undesirable header.

---

Another alternative, but then you might run into thread safety issues, is to just provide functions that operate on a static state variable. I.e. a singleton, a global. Yes this is as bad as it sounds (even though a whole programming language, Modula-2, was based on the idea), but it certainly is a technical option, and might be preferable in certain situations.