# Program crashed when assigning value to a structure field

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am learning C++, recently I encountered a problem and don't know why.

I want to hide the private member fields details from outside users, so I just
declare a void* pointer as the only one private member field, and then declare the
real member fields structure in class' .cpp source file. new this inner hidden 
structure in class constructor, and delete it in class destructor.

Below is my test codes:

### ItemA.h

```
#pragma once

class ItemA
{
private:
    void* pFields;

public:
    ItemA();
    ~ItemA();
};
```

### ItemA.cpp

```
#include "ItemA.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

typedef struct
{
    int    intField;
    string strField;
} HFIELDS, *PHFIELDS;

ItemA::ItemA()
{
    this->pFields = new HFIELDS;
    PHFIELDS pHFIELDS = (PHFIELDS)this->pFields;
    pHFIELDS->intField = 100;
    pHFIELDS->strField = "100";
}

ItemA::~ItemA()
{
    PHFIELDS pHFIELDS = (PHFIELDS)this->pFields;
    delete pHFIELDS;
}
```

### ItemB.h

```
#pragma once

#include "ItemA.h"

class ItemB
{
private:
    void* pFields;
    ItemB();

public:
    ItemB(ItemA &itemA);
    ~ItemB();
};
```

### ItemB.cpp

```
#include "ItemB.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

typedef struct
{
    ItemA* pItemA;
    int    intField;
    string strField;
} HFIELDS, *PHFIELDS;

ItemB::ItemB(ItemA &itemA)
{
    this->pFields = new HFIELDS;
    PHFIELDS pHFIELDS = (PHFIELDS)(this->pFields);
    pHFIELDS->pItemA = &itemA;
    pHFIELDS->intField = 200;
    pHFIELDS->strField = "200";
}


ItemB::~ItemB()
{
    PHFIELDS pHFIELDS = (PHFIELDS)this->pFields;
    delete pHFIELDS;
}
```

### main.cpp

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include "ItemA.h"
#include "ItemB.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    ItemA* pItemA = new ItemA();
    ItemB* pItemB = new ItemB(*pItemA);
    delete pItemB;
    delete pItemA;

    return 0;
}
```

When program execution ran to ItemB's constructor this line it crashed:

> pHFIELDS->strField = "200";

Could somebody tell me what's wrong with it? Thank you.

P.S. The development environment I use is MSVC2013.

Comment: Why would you use a void pointer for this?  You might read about the pimpl idiom: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60570/why-should-the-pimpl-idiom-be-used

Comment: Thanks for your knowledge sharing R.N., I will study it.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) it means `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`)

Comment: You could just declare the `private:` field `class Hstruct *pfield;` *without* defining `class Hstruct` in `ItemA.h`

Comment: Thanks, Basile. One more lesson learned. I will follow the PIMPL idiom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why do you have 2 declarations of HFIELDS and *PHFIELDS

1) In ItemA.cpp

```
typedef struct
{
    int    intField;
    string strField;
} HFIELDS, *PHFIELDS;
```

2) In ItemB.cpp

```
typedef struct
{
    ItemA* pItemA;
    int    intField;
    string strField;
} HFIELDS, *PHFIELDS;
```

What happens is, ItemA.h is included in ItemB so the compiler sees 2 declarations.

Please change name and compile.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Ganesh, your answer helps me. But another question comes, the two structure declarations are in separate cpp files, if this is redefinition problem, why the compiler didn't give me a error or warning?

Comment: separately, this code would have worked for you. when the compiler looks at the same variable name reprezenting 2 different things, it will not be able to resolve.

Comment: i copied all your code into one file to check if it works. That was when my compiler threw me an error saying there is re-declaration.

Comment: I am suspecting that some resolutions can be postponed up to run time. Which might have happend in your case. But i am no expert :)