# How to forward declare vector<B*>* (not vector<B> or vector<B*>)?

Tags: c++, vector, forward-declaration, pimpl-idiom

I know we can insulate a class by using pointer so that the header of the class is not required in header, e.g.:

```
class B;
class A{
    B* b;
};
```

It prevents #include "B.h" in A.h. Now I want to prevent

```
#include <vector>
```

in header, so I try to copy the syntax, use a pointer of vector:

```
class std::vector<B*>;
class A{
    std::vector<B*>* v;
};
```

but it failed to compile, is it possible to prevent include vector header by using pointer of vector?

Comment: The purpose of forward declarations is to reduce compilation time.  When a header changes, there is less to compile.  The definition of vector isn't going to change often, so just include the header

Comment: Also,  vector is a template.

Comment: Also,  don't add or change anything in the std namespace

Comment: @JaredDykstra you are allowed to add explicit specializations of existing functions in `namespace std`

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for:

```
#include <vector>

class B;
class A
{
    std::vector<B *> *v;
};
```

It's not permitted to attempt to provide your own declarations for members of `namespace std;`

If you do not want your header to include `<vector>` then you cannot use any type involving `vector` in your class. You could use a [pImpl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60570/why-should-the-pimpl-idiom-be-used) instead.

Answer (score 0):

No need of doing class std::vector;
define class A as

```
#include <vector>
class B;
class A
{
  std::vector<B*> *v; 
};
```

Or you can `typedef std::vector<B*> VEC_PTR_B_T;` and use `VEC_PTR_B_T *v` in class A.