# Cannot use a C++/CLI DLL unless Windows 10 SDK is installed

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

We have developed a C++ library that does a little bit of data interpretation, mostly converting raw byte streams into JSON strings and also collecting raw data packages and returning the collection as a binary file (byte stream).

This library is written with pure C++ STL without any other libraries as dependencies and is used successfully in Android and iOS projects.

For a new C# project for Windows Desktops, developed by external partners we have built, a [PIMPL class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60570/why-should-the-pimpl-idiom-be-used) in C++/CLI that enables easy integration of the already existing code base. In Visual Studio we compile the C++ library into a static library with clang/LLVM and use it in the [Visual C++/CLI Wrapper project](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-development/creating-ccli-wrapper/) as a dependency to build a DLL that we provide for our partner.

This setup took a little time but it works now fine and we are really happy about the development.

But when we tried to get a Demo running on a different PC we encountered serious problems: It is not possible to load this DLL on a "clean" system. When trying to load it in our application (or a DLL Dependency Walker for that matter) it throws a

After some hours of experimenting I've narrowed it down to the Windows 10 SDK that seems to be necessary to load this DLL.

My guess is that it has something to do with some compiler/linker setting in Visual Studio, but I have no idea which one...

Edit:
All VC++ redistributables (2010-2017, x86&x64 just to be sure) as well as the .Net Framework 4.7 and .Net Core Redistributable are installed.

Comment: Is the Visual Studio C++ runtime for the version of the Visual Studio compiler you're using installed on the target PC?

Comment: Forgetting to deploy the C++ runtime DLLs throws a

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to mention, of course all the VC++ redistributables are installed on the machine.